# How do I keep Python print from adding newlines or spaces?

Tags: python, printing, formatting, python-2.x

In python, if I say

```
print 'h'
```

I get the letter h and a newline.  If I say

```
print 'h',
```

I get the letter h and no newline.  If I say

```
print 'h',
print 'm',
```

I get the letter h, a space, and the letter m.  How can I prevent Python from printing the space?

The print statements are different iterations of the same loop so I can't just use the + operator.

Comment: My current experiments suggest there is no *trailing* space. Instead, it is a leading space *if and only if* the preceding output operation was a `print`. To see yourself, interleave some calls to `print '.',` and `sys.stdout.write(',')`. This is crazy.  Why should it 'remember' what came before, and change behaviour accordingly?

Answer (score 203, accepted):

```
import sys

sys.stdout.write('h')
sys.stdout.flush()

sys.stdout.write('m')
sys.stdout.flush()
```

You need to call [`sys.stdout.flush()`](https://docs.python.org/library/io.html#io.IOBase.flush) because otherwise it will hold the text in a buffer and you won't see it.

Comment: This worked great for me.  Just don't forget to do a sys.stdout.flush() when you're ready to display it on screen, otherwise it will hold it in a buffer and you won't see it.  I use this to give visual feedback that a script is still running when it's going through a long while or for loop.

Comment: If typing is an issue, don't forget you can do:
log = sys.stdout.write

Comment: To use this, you have to import `sys` by using `import sys`

Comment: As a variation on this idiom:
`prynt = lambda x : sys.stdout.write (str(x))`

Answer (score 306):

In [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function), use

```
print('h', end='')
```

to suppress the endline terminator, and

```
print('a', 'b', 'c', sep='')
```

to suppress the whitespace separator between items. See [the documentation for `print`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#print)

Comment: You can `from __future__ import print_function` in Python 2.6

Comment: from __future__ import print_function will break any other print statements using the old syntax in the same module, so whilst it's more elegant than sys.stdout.write, it can be more work to make the change.

Comment: Also handy, if you need to overwrite the last line, use ```end='\r'```

Answer (score 44):

Greg is right-- you can use sys.stdout.write

Perhaps, though, you should consider refactoring your algorithm to accumulate a list of <whatevers> and then

```
lst = ['h', 'm']
print  "".join(lst)
```

Comment: as a variation on this idiom:

`print ''.join(map(str,[1, '+', 2, '=', 3]))`

Answer (score 27):

Or use a `+`, i.e.:

```
>>> print 'me'+'no'+'likee'+'spacees'+'pls'
menolikeespaceespls
```

Just make sure all are concatenate-able objects.

Comment: or, you can convert them:
print str(me)+str(no)+str(likee)+str(spacees)+str(pls)

Comment: This still adds a newline.

Answer (score 19):

```
Python 2.5.2 (r252:60911, Sep 27 2008, 07:03:14)
[GCC 4.3.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print "hello",; print "there"
hello there
>>> print "hello",; sys.stdout.softspace=False; print "there"
hellothere
```

But really, you should use `sys.stdout.write` directly.

Answer (score 17):

For completeness, one other way is to clear the softspace value after performing the write.

```
import sys
print "hello",
sys.stdout.softspace=0
print "world",
print "!"
```

prints `helloworld !`

Using stdout.write() is probably more convenient for most cases though.

Comment: according to [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.softspace) **This attribute is not used to control the print statement, but to allow the implementation of print to keep track of its internal state.**

Answer (score 13):

This may look stupid, but seems to be the simplest:

```
    print 'h',
    print '\bm'
```

Comment: This still adds a newline.

Answer (score 8):

Regain control of your console! Simply:

```
from __past__ import printf
```

where `__past__.py` contains:

```
import sys
def printf(fmt, *varargs):
    sys.stdout.write(fmt % varargs)
```

then:

```
>>> printf("Hello, world!\n")
Hello, world!
>>> printf("%d %d %d\n", 0, 1, 42)
0 1 42
>>> printf('a'); printf('b'); printf('c'); printf('\n')
abc
>>>
```

Bonus extra: If you don't like `print >> f, ...`, you can extending this caper to fprintf(f, ...).

Comment: I loved this :D. A good thing about it is that it implicitly kills the problem of `"something %s" % x` where `x` is a tuple...

Answer (score 7):

I am not adding a new answer. I am just putting the best marked answer in a better format.
I can see that the best answer by rating is using `sys.stdout.write(someString)`. You can try this out:

```
    import sys
    Print = sys.stdout.write
    Print("Hello")
    Print("World")
```

will yield:

```
HelloWorld
```

That is all.

Answer (score 4):

In python 2.6:

```
>>> print 'h','m','h'
h m h
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> print('h',end='')
h>>> print('h',end='');print('m',end='');print('h',end='')
hmh>>>
>>> print('h','m','h',sep='');
hmh
>>>
```

So using print_function from __future__ you can set explicitly the **sep** and **end** parameteres of print function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use print like the printf function in C.

e.g.

print "%s%s" % (x, y)

Comment: This still adds a newline afterwards. The OP wanted to call print multiple times over a loop and not have any spaces or newlines in between.

Answer (score 1):

```
print("{0}{1}{2}".format(a, b, c))
```

Comment: This still adds a newline afterwards. The OP wanted to call print multiple times over a loop and not have any spaces or newlines in between.

Comment: … but it is a good idea to have a read of the format documentation:
[string — § Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) and [Built-in Types — § String Methods — str.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

Answer (score 0):

`sys.stdout.write` is (in Python 2) the only robust solution. Python 2 printing is insane. Consider this code:

```
print "a",
print "b",
```

This will print `a b`, leading you to suspect that it is printing a trailing space. But this is not correct. Try this instead:

```
print "a",
sys.stdout.write("0")
print "b",
```

This will print `a0b`. How do you explain that? ***Where have the spaces gone?***

I still can't quite make out what's really going on here. Could somebody look over my best guess:

*My attempt at deducing the rules when you have a trailing `,` on your `print`*:

First, let's assume that `print    ,` (in Python 2) doesn't print any whitespace (spaces *nor* newlines).

Python 2 does, however, pay attention to how you are printing - are you using `print`, or `sys.stdout.write`, or something else? If you make two *consecutive* calls to `print`, then Python will insist on putting in a space in between the two.

Answer (score 0):

```
print('''first line \
second line''')
```

it will produce

> first line second line

Answer (score -1):

```
import sys
a=raw_input()
for i in range(0,len(a)):
       sys.stdout.write(a[i])
```

Comment: The accepted answer by Greg Hewgill already mentioned sys.stdout.write().