# How to print without a newline or space

Tags: python, trailing-newline

Consider these examples using `print` in Python:

```py
>>> for i in range(4): print('.')
.
.
.
.
>>> print('.', '.', '.', '.')
. . . .
```

Either a newline or a space is added between each value. How can I avoid that, so that the output is `....` instead? In other words, how can I "append" strings to the standard output stream?

Comment: For those who search the string formating documentation of python: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

Comment: Looks like a similar question had been asked previously: [https://stackoverflow.com/q/255147/9325817](https://stackoverflow.com/q/255147/9325817)

Comment: Bit late to the party, but why not `print("." * 10)`?

Comment: Explanation on [how to use `sep` and `end` in python print statement](https://www.codingeek.com/tutorials/python/python-io-user-input-ouput/#2_how_to_print_output_to_the_screen)

Answer (score 3294, accepted):

In Python 3, you can use the `sep=` and `end=` parameters of the [`print`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#print) function:

To not add a newline to the end of the string:

```
print('.', end='')
```

To not add a space between all the function arguments you want to print:

```
print('a', 'b', 'c', sep='')
```

You can pass any string to either parameter, and you can use both parameters at the same time.

If you are having trouble with buffering, you can flush the output by adding `flush=True` keyword argument:

```
print('.', end='', flush=True)
```

### Python 2.6 and 2.7

From Python 2.6 you can either import the `print` function from Python 3 using the [`__future__` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html):

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

which allows you to use the Python 3 solution above.

However, note that the `flush` keyword is not available in the version of the `print` function imported from `__future__` in Python 2; it only works in Python 3, more specifically 3.3 and later. In earlier versions you'll still need to flush manually with a call to `sys.stdout.flush()`. You'll also have to rewrite all other print statements in the file where you do this import.

Or you can use [`sys.stdout.write()`](https://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.stdout)

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write('.')
```

You may also need to call

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```

to ensure `stdout` is flushed immediately.

Comment: Thanks! In Python 3.6.3, that flush=True is crucial, or else it doesn't work as intended.

Comment: Can someone explain why would I need to `flush` and what does it do actually?

Comment: It's a few months late, but to answer @Rishav flush empties the buffer and displays the output right now. Without flush you might have your exact text printed eventually, but only when the system gets around to processing the graphics instead of the IO.  Flush makes the text visible immediately by "flushing" the cache.

Comment: If you're having trouble with buffering you can unbuffer all python output with `python -u my.py`.  This is often a good idea if you want to watch progress in real-time.

Comment: I use format strings and do not want a new line between the string and the **?**:`line = f"{line[6:]}?"` Is there also an "end"?

Answer (score 303):

For Python 2 and earlier, it should be as simple as described in *[Re: How does one print without a CR?](http://legacy.python.org/search/hypermail/python-1992/0115.html)* by [Guido van Rossum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guido_van_Rossum) (paraphrased):

> Is it possible to print something, but not automatically have a
> carriage return appended to it?

Yes, append a comma after the last argument to print. For instance, this loop prints the numbers 0..9 on a line separated by spaces. Note the parameterless "print" that adds the final newline:

```
>>> for i in range(10):
...     print i,
... else:
...     print
...
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
>>>
```

Comment: This is specifically listed in the question as undesirable behavior because of the spaces

Comment: On the contrary, the answer should be deleted for two reasons: it has undesirable side effects which you can't disable (included extra spaces), and It isn't forward compatible with python 3 (the parenthesis force a conversion to a tuple).  I expect these sorts of shoddy constructs from PHP, not Python.  So it's best to not ever use this.

Comment: // , This is the simplest way to get it done in Python 2, though, and there is a LOT of one-off code out there for really old OSes. Probably not the best solution, or even recommended. 
However, one of the great advantages of StackOverflow is that it lets us know what weirdo tricks are out there. KDP, would you include a quick warning at the top about what @Eric Leschinski said? It does make sense, after all.

Comment: @nathanbasanese Simple or not, it has a side effect that *the asker explicitly does not want*. Downvoted.

Comment: How can I get rid of that space after each N i.e. I want `0123456..`

Comment: You didn't answer the question.  "How to print without newline or ***SPACE***?"  He specifically says without spaces.

Comment: @shrewmouse `print '\b'+str(i),`

Comment: @Joe', you are still printing a space.  It's just masked by the backspace.

Comment: @Cylindric: often people find questions via google that aren't a perfect match for what *they* want, but the answer still works for them.  Presumably most of the 291 upvotes on this were from people who were fine with a trailing space, unlike the requirements in the question.  That's just how SO works, especially for FAQs that come up in many different contexts.  It doesn't *justify* this answer or mean any of that is a good thing, it just explains how we got here and tells us that this answer actually helped (or at least looked good) for a lot of people.

Comment: Probably fair to say that the answer doesn't deserve to be deleted, but it definitely can benefit from having language that calls out its drawbacks, of which there are many.

Comment: The answer is dated and incorrect for Python3.

Dowvnote because the author did not update this answer to indicate that it is for legacy code. And the answer is an incomplete solution to the posted problem.

Comment: Indeed, does not answer the question (still spaces between i's) and does not work in python 3, I tried `print(i,)` and `print(i),`, both writes new lines and the second one writes a `(None,)` between each i's. Edit: just find out right after, works with `print(i, end="")`, and `print` in `else` must have parenthesis, so `print()`.

Answer (score 179):

*Note: The title of this question used to be something like "How to printf in Python"*

Since people may come here looking for it based on the title, Python also supports printf-style substitution:

```
>>> strings = [ "one", "two", "three" ]
>>>
>>> for i in xrange(3):
...     print "Item %d: %s" % (i, strings[i])
...
Item 0: one
Item 1: two
Item 2: three
```

And, you can handily multiply string values:

```
>>> print "." * 10
..........
```

Comment: Indeed, it is missing the point. :) Since there was already a great answer to the question I was just elaborating on some related techniques that might prove useful.

Comment: Based on the title of the question, I believe this answer is more appropriate analog to how one commonly uses printf in C/C++

Comment: This answers the title of the question, but not the body.  That said, it provided me with what I was looking for.  :)

Comment: it's not the answer to the question

Comment: @Vanuan, I explained in the bottom of my answer that the title of the question changed at some point. :)

Comment: Is there a way to use the printf style and get no newlines?  print "%s, ", % i ... doesn't work. :-/

Comment: This answer is not relevant anymore.

Answer (score 100):

Use the Python 3-style print function for Python 2.6+ *(it will also break any existing keyworded print statements in the same file)*.

```
# For Python 2 to use the print() function, removing the print keyword
from __future__ import print_function
for x in xrange(10):
    print('.', end='')
```

To not ruin all your Python 2 print keywords, create a separate `printf.py` file:

```
# printf.py

from __future__ import print_function

def printf(str, *args):
    print(str % args, end='')
```

Then, use it in your file:

```
from printf import printf
for x in xrange(10):
    printf('.')
print 'done'
#..........done
```

More examples showing the printf style:

```
printf('hello %s', 'world')
printf('%i %f', 10, 3.14)
#hello world10 3.140000
```

Answer (score 48):

How to print on the same line:

```
import sys
for i in xrange(0,10):
   sys.stdout.write(".")
   sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Real time output of status and still relevant 10+ years later in Python 3 !

Answer (score 42):

The `print` function in Python 3.x has an optional `end` parameter that lets you modify the ending character:

```py
print("HELLO", end="")
print("HELLO")
```

Output:

> HELLOHELLO

There's also `sep` for separator:

```py
print("HELLO", "HELLO", "HELLO", sep="")
```

Output:

> HELLOHELLOHELLO

If you wanted to use this in Python 2.x just add this at the **start** of your file:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Comment: what does "sep" do?

Comment: @McPeppr I know that this is old but I have edited the answer nonetheless for more clarity. Check it now.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. sep will come in handy. So far I used sep.join(list) to concatenate elements of a list with a separator in between - perfect for writing csv-files

Answer (score 24):

Using *functools.partial* to create a new function called *printf*:

```
>>> import functools

>>> printf = functools.partial(print, end="")

>>> printf("Hello world\n")
Hello world
```

It is an easy way to wrap a function with default parameters.

Comment: I used to want to do that but couldn't because `otherfunction = function(1)` would just store the result of `function(1)`, not turn `otherfunction` into a wrapper. Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

In Python 3+, [`print`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#print) is a function. When you call

```
print('Hello, World!')
```

Python translates it to

```
print('Hello, World!', end='\n')
```

You can change `end` to whatever you want.

```
print('Hello, World!', end='')
print('Hello, World!', end=' ')
```

Answer (score 14):

In Python 2.x, you can just add `,` at the end of the `print` function, so it won't print on a new line.

Comment: // , This actually made it print out nothing. Don't we need to then add another print statement without an argument at the end, as shown in http://stackoverflow.com/a/493500/2146138? Would you be willing to edit this answer with a reeeally short two or three line example?

Comment: The OP doesn;t want a space appended

Comment: Didn't answer the question.  No spaces.

Comment: This no longer works in Python 2.x and only answers half of what the OP wanted. Why 16 upvotes?

Comment: @TheTechRobo36414519: It was 25 upvotes and 9 downvotes (total of 16). Since then it got one upvote and one downvote (so right now the total is still 16).

Answer (score 13):

Python **3**:

```
print('.', end='')
```

Python **2.6+**:

```
from __future__ import print_function # needs to be first statement in file
print('.', end='')
```

Python **<=2.5**:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write('.')
```

If extra space is OK after each print, in Python 2:

```
print '.',
```

**Misleading** in Python 2 - **avoid**:

```
print('.'), # Avoid this if you want to remain sane
# This makes it look like print is a function, but it is not.
# This is the `,` creating a tuple and the parentheses enclose an expression.
# To see the problem, try:
print('.', 'x'), # This will print `('.', 'x') `
```

Answer (score 10):

In general, there are two ways to do this:

**Print without a newline in Python 3.x**

Append nothing after the print statement and remove '\n' by using `end=''`, as:

```
>>> print('hello')
hello  # Appending '\n' automatically
>>> print('world')
world # With previous '\n' world comes down

# The solution is:
>>> print('hello', end='');print(' world'); # End with anything like end='-' or end=" ", but not '\n'
hello world # It seems to be the correct output
```

**Another Example in Loop**:

```
for i in range(1,10):
    print(i, end='.')
```

**Print without a newline in Python 2.x**

Adding a trailing comma says: after print, ignore `\n`.

```
>>> print "hello",; print" world"
hello world
```

**Another Example in Loop**:

```
for i in range(1,10):
    print "{} .".format(i),
```

You can visit this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-without-newline-python/).

Comment: What about the space?

Comment: use `end=" "` e.g.: print('hello', end='' ");print('world')

Comment: Your 2.7 solution does not remove the space.

Comment: I mention that remove '\n' not space, space is by default in python2. See what this looks: `print 'hello' ;print'there'` in https://paiza.io/projects/e/35So9iUPfMdIORGzJTb2NQ

Comment: Right, that is why your answer was down-voted.  You did not answer the question, "How to print without newline or space?".  Your answer for 2.x doesn't answer the question.  You answer for 3.0 is the same as many of the other answers that were posted over nine years ago.  Simply stated, this answer adds nothing useful to the community and you should delete it.

Comment: I have mentioned that Print without newline in Python 2.x in answer. It does the work as asked in question, i have checked it twice. I think that my answer can be simple one that's why i post it. Anyway thanks for your suggestion. Should i delete it?

Comment: You just said "I mention that remove '\n' not space, space is by default in python2. See what this looks: print 'hello' ;print'there'".  You just admitted that your code does not answer the question (i.e. your code does not remove the SPACE).  Your python 3 example is identical to most of the other answers; it adds nothing new.  Yes, you should delete your answer.

Answer (score 9):

You can try:

```
import sys
import time
# Keeps the initial message in buffer.
sys.stdout.write("\rfoobar bar black sheep")
sys.stdout.flush()
# Wait 2 seconds
time.sleep(2)
# Replace the message with a new one.
sys.stdout.write("\r"+'hahahahaaa             ')
sys.stdout.flush()
# Finalize the new message by printing a return carriage.
sys.stdout.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 9):

Just use `end=''`

```py
for i in range(5):
  print('a',end='')

# aaaaa
```

Answer (score 8):

just use the `end` ="" or `sep` =""

```
>>> for i in range(10):
        print('.', end = "")
```

output:

```
.........
```

Answer (score 7):

I recently had the same problem...

I solved it by doing:

```
import sys, os

# Reopen standard output with "newline=None".
# in this mode,
# Input:  accepts any newline character, outputs as '\n'
# Output: '\n' converts to os.linesep

sys.stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), "w", newline=None)

for i in range(1,10):
    print(i)
```

This works on both Unix and Windows, but I have not tested it on Mac OS X.

Comment: Breaks `sys.__stdout__`

Answer (score 6):

You can do the same in Python 3 as follows:

```
#!usr/bin/python

i = 0
while i<10 :
    print('.', end='')
    i = i+1
```

And execute it with `python filename.py` or `python3 filename.py`.

Answer (score 5):

[lenooh satisfied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-a-newline-or-space/4348063#4348063) my query. I discovered this article while searching for 'python suppress newline'. I'm using [IDLE 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE) on Raspberry Pi to develop Python 3.2 for [PuTTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY).

I wanted to create a progress bar on the PuTTY command line. I didn't want the page scrolling away. I wanted a horizontal line to reassure the user from freaking out that the program hasn't cruncxed to a halt nor been sent to lunch on a merry infinite loop - as a plea to 'leave me be, I'm doing fine, but this may take some time.' interactive message - like a progress bar in text.

The `print('Skimming for', search_string, '\b! .001', end='')` initializes the message by preparing for the next screen-write, which will print three backspaces as ⌫⌫⌫ rubout and then a period, wiping off '001' and extending the line of periods.

After `search_string` parrots user input, the `\b!` trims the exclamation point of my `search_string` text to back over the space which `print()` otherwise forces, properly placing the punctuation. That's followed by a space and the first 'dot' of the 'progress bar' which I'm simulating.

Unnecessarily, the message is also then primed with the page number (formatted to a length of three with leading zeros) to take notice from the user that progress is being processed and which will also reflect the count of periods we will later build out to the right.

```
import sys

page=1
search_string=input('Search for?',)
print('Skimming for', search_string, '\b! .001', end='')
sys.stdout.flush() # the print function with an end='' won't print unless forced
while page:
    # some stuff…
    # search, scrub, and build bulk output list[], count items,
    # set done flag True
    page=page+1 #done flag set in 'some_stuff'
    sys.stdout.write('\b\b\b.'+format(page, '03')) #<-- here's the progress bar meat
    sys.stdout.flush()
    if done: #( flag alternative to break, exit or quit)
        print('\nSorting', item_count, 'items')
        page=0 # exits the 'while page' loop
list.sort()
for item_count in range(0, items)
    print(list[item_count])

#print footers here
if not (len(list)==items):
    print('#error_handler')
```

The progress bar meat is in the `sys.stdout.write('\b\b\b.'+format(page, '03'))` line. First, to erase to the left, it backs up the cursor over the three numeric characters with the '\b\b\b' as ⌫⌫⌫ rubout and drops a new period to add to the progress bar length. Then it writes three digits of the page it has progressed to so far. Because `sys.stdout.write()` waits for a full buffer or the output channel to close, the `sys.stdout.flush()` forces the immediate write. `sys.stdout.flush()` is built into the end of `print()` which is bypassed with `print(txt, end='' )`. Then the code loops through its mundane time intensive operations while it prints nothing more until it returns here to wipe three digits back, add a period and write three digits again, incremented.

The three digits wiped and rewritten is by no means necessary - it's just a flourish which exemplifies `sys.stdout.write()` versus `print()`. You could just as easily prime with a period and forget the three fancy backslash-b ⌫ backspaces (of course not writing formatted page counts as well) by just printing the period bar longer by one each time through - without spaces or newlines using just the `sys.stdout.write('.'); sys.stdout.flush()` pair.

Please note that the Raspberry Pi IDLE 3 Python shell does not honor the backspace as ⌫ rubout, but instead prints a space, creating an apparent list of fractions instead.

Answer (score 5):

You want to print something in the *for* loop right; but you don't want it print in new line every time...

For example:

```
 for i in range (0,5):
   print "hi"

 OUTPUT:
    hi
    hi
    hi
    hi
    hi
```

---

But you want it to print like this:
hi hi hi hi hi hi right????

Just add a comma after printing "hi".

Example:

```
for i in range (0,5):
    print "hi",
```

OUTPUT:

```
hi hi hi hi hi
```

Comment: No, the OP wants hihihihihi, not hi hi hi hi hi

Answer (score 5):

Many of these answers seem a little complicated. In Python 3.x you simply do this:

```
print(<expr>, <expr>, ..., <expr>, end=" ")
```

The default value of end is `"\n"`. We are simply changing it to a space or you can also use `end=""` (no space) to do what `printf` normally does.

Answer (score 5):

You will notice that all the above answers are correct. But I wanted to make a shortcut to always writing the " end='' " parameter in the end.

You could define a function like

```
def Print(*args, sep='', end='', file=None, flush=False):
    print(*args, sep=sep, end=end, file=file, flush=flush)
```

It would accept all the number of parameters. Even it will accept all the other parameters, like file, flush, etc. and with the same name.

Comment: It do not run, it complaints that `*arg` is in beginning (python 2.7), and putting it at the end did run, but did not work completely right. I defined a function that only took `Print(*args)`, and then just called print with `sep='', end=''`. And now it works as I want. So one upvote for the idea.

Answer (score 3):

```
 for i in range(0, 5): #setting the value of (i) in the range 0 to 5 
     print(i)
```

The above code gives the following output:

```
 0    
 1
 2
 3
 4
```

But if you want to print all these output in a straight line then all you should do is add an attribute called    end() to print.

```
 for i in range(0, 5): #setting the value of (i) in the range 0 to 5 
     print(i, end=" ")
```

Output:

```
 0 1 2 3 4
```

And not just a space, you can also add other endings for your output. For example,

```
 for i in range(0, 5): #setting the value of (i) in the range 0 to 5 
     print(i, end=", ")
```

Output:

```
 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,
```

Remember:

```
 Note: The [for variable in range(int_1, int_2):] always prints till the variable is 1

 less than it's limit. (1 less than int_2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Or have a function like:

```
def Print(s):
    return sys.stdout.write(str(s))
```

Then now:

```
for i in range(10): # Or `xrange` for the Python 2 version
    Print(i)
```

Outputs:

```
0123456789
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in xrange(0,10): print '\b.',
```

This worked in both 2.7.8 & 2.5.2 ([Enthought Canopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthought) and OS X terminal, respectively) -- no module imports or time travel required.

Comment: That prints backspace characters to standard output. It might *look* correct if standard output happens to be a terminal, but if it's redirected to a file that file will contain control characters.

Comment: True, but I can't imagine that anyone would want to use this for anything other than a low-tech progress bar ...

Comment: Nevertheless, the Python code does not do the same thing as the C code in the question.

Comment: you can test with `sys.stdout.isatty()` if not redirected to a file.

Answer (score 1):

To print without ending a line, you can do this:

```py
print("Hello", end='')
```

So if you add

```py
print(" Hello again!", end='')
```

The output will look like this:

```
Hello Hello again!
```

Comment: I get "invalid syntax" (Python 2.6)

Answer (score 0):

Python3 :

```
print('Hello',end='')
```

Example :

```
print('Hello',end=' ')
print('world')
```

Output:
`Hello world`

This method add spearator between provided texts :

```
print('Hello','world',sep=',')
```

Output:`Hello,world`

Answer (score 0):

Here are three codes for you to choose one:

```py
print("".join(["." for i in range(4)]))
```

or

```py
print("." + "." + "." + ".")
```

or

```py
print(".", ".", ".", ".", sep="")
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `end=''` to the print function e.g.:

```
print(i+1, end='')
```

Answer (score -4):

You do not need to import any library. Just use the delete character:

```
BS = u'\0008' # The Unicode point for the "delete" character
for i in range(10):print(BS + "."),
```

This removes the newline and the space (^_^)*.