# How can I print multiple things on the same line, one at a time?

Tags: python, printing, stdout, line-breaks

I want to run a script, which basically shows an output like this:

```
Installing XXX...               [DONE]
```

Currently, I print `Installing XXX...` first and then I print `[DONE]`.

How can I instead print `Installing xxx...` and `[DONE]` on the same line?

---

<sub>For the specific problem of writing a new message on the same line, **replacing what was there before**, please see [How to overwrite the previous print to stdout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419389). **Most** answers here interpreted the question as being about writing new text **at the end of** the current line.</sub>

<sub>For the problem of using a single `print` to output multiple things at once, see [How can I print multiple things (fixed text and/or variable values) on the same line, all at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286401/).</sub>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I keep Python print from adding newlines or spaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255147/how-do-i-keep-python-print-from-adding-newlines-or-spaces)

Comment: Answers to this question don't mention that sometimes you want to clear the line, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45263205

Answer (score 334):

**Python 3 Solution**

The `print()` function accepts an `end` parameter which defaults to `\n` (new line). Setting it to an empty string prevents it from issuing a new line at the end of the line.

```
def install_xxx():
    print("Installing XXX...      ", end="", flush=True)

install_xxx()
print("[DONE]")
```

**Python 2 Solution**

Putting a comma on the end of the `print()` line prevents `print()` from issuing a new line (you should note that there will be an extra space at the end of the output).

```
def install_xxx():
   print "Installing XXX...      ",

install_xxx()
print "[DONE]"
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Had only seen stdout solutions so far. Really good to know that.

Comment: This doesn't work if you have both prints and a time consuming action in between (all in the same function / indentation level). Before the action starts, there is no output at all and after it is finished the output appears as whole

Comment: That is probably more a function of the output buffering preformed by the OS for the process as a whole, which is not a python-specific problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705 for a python-specific workaround.

Comment: Without a newline, you probably want to explicitly flush the buffer. Use `print("...", end="", flush=True)` in Python 3, in Python 2 add a `sys.stdout.flush()` call.

Comment: in python 3.x you'll want to add a "\r" to end to replace the printed line VS appending to the end of it `print("Progress: {}%".format(var), end="\r", flush=True)`

Comment: If you want to overwrite the line, then instead of `end=""` put `end="\r"` so the cursor starts over again. or in python 2, append `"\r"` to your string. Watch for short lines leaving kruft.  May want to pad with `str.ljust(longest)`.

Comment: Just in case someone also stumbles upon this: you also have to adjust the length of the printed string to fit into a terminal line. Otherwise, none of the methods in this thread will work (at least not on macOS 10.13). ; )

Comment: If one needs to keep "printing" at the same line (i.e. multiple `print()`), `\r` must be prepended. For example, `print(f"\r* [{file}] Line {l_idx} [{len(line)}]", end="", flush=True)`.

Answer (score 110):

You can simply use this:

```
print 'something',
...
print ' else',
```

and the output will be

```
something else
```

no need to overkill by `import sys`. Pay attention to comma symbol at the end.

**Python 3+**
`print("some string", end="");` to remove the newline insert at the end. Read more by `help(print);`

Comment: Note there are two spaces by using this method

Comment: This is the simplest and the most efficient answer.

Comment: This does not work when arguments of print are in parentheses. This works: <print "hello",; print("hello")> but this doesnt work <print("hello",); print("hello")>

Comment: @MayankJaiswal This does work with the parens.
print('hello'),

Comment: `print` function has slightly different syntax in python 2 VS 3.

Comment: How does it work in Python 3.5+? I tried `print("..."),` and `print("...",)`. Neither worked.

Comment: @CGFoX `print("string", end="");` - read the docs `help(print);`

Comment: if the `…` is some function that takes some time to complete, then `something` doesn't print until `else` prints.

Comment: `print("some string", end="", flush=True)` does it for me!

Comment: In some cases, will need to add `flush=True` (ie `print("context", end="", flush=True)`. Otherwise, it won't show anything

Answer (score 68):

You should use backspace '**\r**' or ('**\x08**') char to go back on previous position in console output

Python 2+:

```python
import time
import sys

def backspace(n):
    sys.stdout.write((b'\x08' * n).decode()) # use \x08 char to go back   

for i in range(101):                        # for 0 to 100
    s = str(i) + '%'                        # string for output
    sys.stdout.write(s)                     # just print
    sys.stdout.flush()                      # needed for flush when using \x08
    backspace(len(s))                       # back n chars    
    time.sleep(0.2)                         # sleep for 200ms
```

Python 3:

```python
import time   

def backline():        
    print('\r', end='')                     # use '\r' to go back


for i in range(101):                        # for 0 to 100
    s = str(i) + '%'                        # string for output
    print(s, end='')                        # just print and flush
    backline()                              # back to the beginning of line    
    time.sleep(0.2)                         # sleep for 200ms
```

This code will count from 0% to 100% on one line. Final value will be:

```
> python test.py
100%
```

Additional info about flush in this case here: [Why do python print statements that contain 'end=' arguments behave differently in while-loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047372/why-do-python-print-statements-that-contain-end-arguments-behave-differently)

Comment: To clarify, it looks like the commented-out code in this example is for Python 2, and the non-commented lines are for Python 3.

Comment: bouth lines will work fine in Python 3. If you use '\x08' as a backspace you need to flush the output stream - print((b'\x08' * n).decode(), end='', flush=True)

Comment: The carriage return '\r' goes back to the beginning of the line, so the '* n' is unnecessary

Answer (score 42):

Use `sys.stdout.write('Installing XXX... ')` and `sys.stdout.write('Done')`. In this way, you have to add the new line by hand with `"\n"` if you want to recreate the print functionality. I think that it might be unnecessary to use curses just for this.

Comment: I personally prefer this solution to the higher voted one because it works the exact same way on python2.x and python3.x without needing to rely on `__future__` imports or anything like that.

Answer (score 30):

## Most simple:

#### Python 3

```
    print('\r' + 'something to be override', end='')
```

It means it will back the cursor to beginning, than will print something and will end in the same line. If in a loop it will start printing in the same place it starts.

Comment: Cool! Works in Windows as well.

Comment: Thanks this works fine for me! I think that ``print(’something to be override’, end=‘\r’)`` is simpler, though.

Answer (score 18):

None of the answers worked for me since they all paused until a new line was encountered. I wrote a simple helper:

```
def print_no_newline(string):
    import sys
    sys.stdout.write(string)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

To test it:

```
import time
print_no_newline('hello ')
# Simulate a long task
time.sleep(2)
print('world')
```

"hello " will first print out and flush to the screen before the sleep. After that you can use standard print.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what i needed aka .flush()

Answer (score 13):

`sys.stdout.write` will print without return carriage

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write("installing xxx")
sys.stdout.write(".")
```

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Input_and_output#printing_without_commas_or_newlines

Answer (score 11):

Python appends newline as an end to print. Use end=' ' for python3 for  print method to append a space instead of a newline. for python2 use comma at end of print statement.

```
print('Foo', end=' ')
print('Bar')
```

Answer (score 9):

Print has an optional `end` argument, it is what printed in the end.
The default is a newline, but you can change it to empty string. e.g. `print("hello world!", end="")`

Comment: This is in python 3. In python 2 you can simply `print 'something',`. The comma at the end prevents the addition of a newline.

Answer (score 9):

This simple example will print 1-10 on the same line.

```
for i in range(1,11):
    print (i, end=" ")
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to overwrite the previous line (rather than continually adding to it), you can combine `\r` with  `print(),` at the end of the print statement. For example,

```
from time import sleep

for i in xrange(0, 10):
    print("\r{0}".format(i)),
    sleep(.5)

print("...DONE!")
```

will count 0 to 9, replacing the old number in the console. The `"...DONE!"` will print on the same line as the last counter, 9.

In your case for the OP, this would allow the console to display percent complete of the install as a "progress bar", where you can define a begin and end character position, and update the markers in between.

```
print("Installing |XXXXXX              | 30%"),
```

Answer (score 4):

Here a 2.7-compatible version derived from the 3.0 version by @Vadim-Zin4uk:

**Python 2**

```
import time

for i in range(101):                        # for 0 to 100
    s = str(i) + '%'                        # string for output
    print '{0}\r'.format(s),                # just print and flush

    time.sleep(0.2)
```

For that matter, the 3.0 solution provided looks a little bloated. For example, the backspace method doesn't make use of the integer argument and could probably be done away with altogether.

**Python 3**

```
import time

for i in range(101):                        # for 0 to 100
    s = str(i) + '%'                        # string for output
    print('{0}\r'.format(s), end='')        # just print and flush

    time.sleep(0.2)                         # sleep for 200ms
```

Both have been tested and work.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very old thread, but here's a very thorough answer and sample code.

`\r` is the string representation of *Carriage Return* from the ASCII character set. It's the same as octal `015` [`chr(0o15)`] or hexidecimal `0d` [`chr(0x0d)`] or decimal `13` [`chr(13)`]. See `man ascii` for a boring read. It (`\r`) is a pretty portable representation and is easy enough for people to read. It very simply means to move the carriage on the typewriter all the way back to the start without advancing the paper. It's the `CR` part of `CRLF` which means *Carriage Return and Line Feed*.

`print()` is a function in Python 3. In Python 2 (any version that you'd be interested in using), `print` can be forced into a function by importing its definition from the `__future__` module. The benefit of the `print` function is that you can specify what to print at the end, overriding the default behavior of `\n` to print a newline at the end of every `print()` call.

`sys.stdout.flush` tells Python to flush the output of *standard output*, which is where you send output with `print()` unless you specify otherwise. You can also get the same behavior by running with `python -u` or setting environment variable `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1`, thereby skipping the `import sys` and `sys.stdout.flush()` calls. The amount you gain by doing that is almost exactly zero and isn't very easy to debug if you conveniently forget that you have to do that step before your application behaves properly.

And a sample. Note that this runs perfectly in Python 2 or 3.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys
import time

ANS = 42
FACTORS = {n for n in range(1, ANS + 1) if ANS % n == 0}

for i in range(1, ANS + 1):
    if i in FACTORS:
        print('\r{0:d}'.format(i), end='')
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(ANS / 100.0)
else:
    print()
```

Comment: I think your answer is more suitable for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45263205/python-how-to-print-on-same-line-clearing-previous-text

Answer (score 2):

`print()` has a built in parameter "end" that is by default set to `"\n"`
Calling `print("This is America")` is actually calling `print("This is America", end = "\n")`.
An easy way to do is to call `print("This is America", end ="")`

Answer (score 2):

**This solution in Python 3.X specific:**

When I need to do this, I'll generally just use

```
end=' '
```

For example:

```
# end='' ends the output with a <space> 
print("Welcome to" , end = ' ') 
print("stackoverflow", end = ' ')
```

This outputs as:

```
Welcome to stackoverflow
```

The space in `end=` can be replaced with any character. For example,

```
print("Welcome to" , end = '...') 
print("stackoverflow", end = '!')
```

Which outputs as:

```
Welcome to...stackoverflow!
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you have pre-stored the values in an array, you can call them in the following format:

```
for i in range(0,n):
       print arr[i],
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this [Quora post](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-delete-the-last-printed-line-in-Python-language), with this example which worked for me (python 3),
which was closer to what I needed it for (i.e. erasing the whole previous line).

The example they provide:

```
def clock():
   while True:
       print(datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"), end="\r")
```

For printing the on the same line, as others have suggested, just use `end=""`

Answer (score -3):

I found this solution, and it's working on Python 2.7

```
# Working on Python 2.7 Linux

import time
import sys


def backspace(n):
    print('\r', end='')                     # use '\r' to go back


for i in range(101):                        # for 0 to 100
    s = str(i) + '%'                        # string for output
    sys.stdout.write(string)
    backspace(len(s))                       # back for n chars
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.2)                         # sleep for 200ms
```

Comment: That `print` is incorrect syntax for Python 2.7 and the code doesn't work even with correct syntax.