# Why do python print statements that contain 'end=' arguments behave differently in while-loops?

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm running python version 2.7.3 on MacOSX.

Consider this block of code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import time
x = 0
while x < 5:
    print(x)
    x += 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

If I run this script, I observe the output I expect: The numbers `0` through `4` with a `\n` character appended to each number. Futhermore, each number displays after a one second pause.

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

Now consider this code block:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import time
x = 0
while x < 5:
    print(x, end='')
    x += 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

The output is what I expect, `01234` without the `\n`'s, but the *timing* is unexpected. Rather than displaying each digit after a one-second pause, the process waits four seconds, then displays all five numbers.

Why does `print('string')` behave differently from `print('string', end='')` in while-loops? Is there any way to display the characters without newlines, one second at a time? I tried `sys.stdout.write(str(x))`, but it behaves the same way as `print(end='')`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because the output stream is line-buffered - since it's not explicitly being flushed in between print statements, it waits until it sees a newline to flush the output.

You can force flushing via `sys.stdout.flush()`.

Alternatively if you run Python with the `-u` flag, it will disable line buffering.

Comment: On python 3.5 `print(x, end='', flush=True)` will aso work

Answer (score 7):

This is just python buffering stdout. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/python-output-buffering) has some more info.

You can flush it like this:

```
import sys
from __future__ import print_function
import time
x = 0
while x < 5:
    print(x, end='')
    x += 1
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Alternatively start python `python -u` and it won't be buffered.