# When I'm entering '\t' charecter, output results a newline

Tags: python, tabs, python-3.x, newline

*I'm new in Python, today I was writing a simple test program on Python3.3 based on list. So, I've noticed that when I was entering tab space character `\t`, the output was flashed such that I had enetered **new line character**! A sample is given below:*

```
 def printlist(list_name,tabs=0):
         for items in list_name:
           if isinstance(items,list):
             printlist(items,tabs)
           else:
             print(items)
             for num in range(tabs):
                 print('\t') #tab-stops provide

    list3 = [
             'list no. 3',
             ['tree','stems','root'],
             ['human','hand','leg'],
             ['robot','microprocessor','motor']
            ]

   printlist(list3,1)
```

*And the output is:*

```
    >>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
list no. 3


tree


stems


root


human


hand


leg


robot


microprocessor


motor


>>>
```

*But the output **format** what I intended is:*

```
    list no. 3
    tree
    stems
    root
    human
    hand
    leg
    robot
    microprocessor
    motor
```

[***I want tabs not a new line***]

**So how will it be possible?**

Comment: What should this code really do? Take all list items as a flat list and output each indidivual list item with N tabs indented?

Comment: Print always prints a newline. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598181/python-print-on-same-line

Answer (score 5):

By default, `print()` will end with a newline.  If you want to suppress this behavior specify `end`.

```
print("\t", end="")
```

Documentation is here.  http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#print

Comment: OP also doesn't increment `tabs` in recursive calls, but this is the biggest issue with the output.

Comment: Maybe string multiplication is worth explaining:

`print("\t" * tabs, end="")`

Comment: I'M GETTING SYNTAX ERROR when I'm using: end=""

Comment: In order to figure out what you're doing wrong, you'll need to include enough code to reproduce the syntax error.

Comment: @Tinctorius:  The desired output has unchanging indentation.  There should be no need to increment anything.

Comment: I have placed print("\t", end="") insted of print("\t") but I'm getting syntax error

Comment: I think it was some fault in execution, its now working, thanks

Comment: but I'm getting error (syntax error); I don't understand what's going wrong

Comment: @BiswajitPaul: `print("\t", end="")` is not a syntax error in python 3.3.  I don't know what your problem is, but in order to give you any more information, like I said earlier, you'll have to include enough information to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @recursive actually I have installed both of the python 3.3 and 2.7. So when I've pressed f5 in my editor, the python shell window 2.7 pops up automatically. That's why I was getting error.

Comment: @BiswajitPaul [Since Python 2.6](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html), you can use `from __future__ import print_function` to make it compatible with Python 3. And don't forget to accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior of print is to append a newline: see e.g. http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html