# How can I print multiple things (fixed text and/or variable values) on the same line, all at once?

Tags: python, printing, python-3.x, arguments

I have some code like:

```
score = 100
name = 'Alice'
print('Total score for %s is %s', name, score)
```

I want it to print out `Total score for Alice is 100`, but instead I get `Total score for %s is %s Alice 100`. How can I get everything to print in the right order with the right formatting?

---

<sub>See also: [How can I print multiple things on the same line, one at a time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598181) ; [How do I put a variable’s value inside a string (interpolate it into the string)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960772/)</sub>

Comment: OP of this question originally clearly had a string-formatting approach in mind, which would make the question a) a duplicate and b) caused by a typo (clearly the intent is to use %-style formatting, but the actual `%` operator is not used as required). However, the question received a truly excellent top answer that comprehensively shows approaches to the problem, so I ended up selecting this question as a canonical and editing the question title to reflect the breadth that was assumed in the answer.

Answer (score 684):

There are many ways to do this. To fix your current code using `%`-formatting, you need to pass in a tuple:

1. Pass it as a tuple:

   ```
   print("Total score for %s is %s" % (name, score))
   ```

A tuple with a single element looks like `('this',)`.

Here are some other common ways of doing it:

2. Pass it as a dictionary:

   ```
   print("Total score for %(n)s is %(s)s" % {'n': name, 's': score})
   ```

There's also new-style string formatting, which might be a little easier to read:

3. Use new-style string formatting:

   ```
   print("Total score for {} is {}".format(name, score))
   ```
4. Use new-style string formatting with numbers (useful for reordering or printing the same one multiple times):

   ```
   print("Total score for {0} is {1}".format(name, score))
   ```
5. Use new-style string formatting with explicit names:

   ```
   print("Total score for {n} is {s}".format(n=name, s=score))
   ```
6. Concatenate strings:

   ```
   print("Total score for " + str(name) + " is " + str(score))
   ```

The clearest two, in my opinion:

7. Just pass the values as parameters:

   ```
   print("Total score for", name, "is", score)
   ```

   If you don't want spaces to be inserted automatically by `print` in the above example, change the `sep` parameter:

   ```
   print("Total score for ", name, " is ", score, sep='')
   ```

   If you're using Python 2, won't be able to use the last two because `print` isn't a function in Python 2. You can, however, import this behavior from `__future__`:

   ```
   from __future__ import print_function
   ```
8. Use the new `f`-string formatting in Python 3.6:

   ```
   print(f'Total score for {name} is {score}')
   ```

Comment: of course, there's always the age-old disapproved method: `print("Total score for "+str(name)"+ is "+str(score))`

Comment: @SnakesandCoffee: I'd just do `print("Total score for", name, "is", score)`

Comment: My +1. These days I prefer the `.format()` as more readable than the older `% (tuple)` -- even though I have seen tests that show the `%` interpolation is faster. The `print('xxx', a, 'yyy', b)` is also fine for simple cases. I recommend also to learn `.format_map()` with dictionary as the argument, and with `'ssss {key1} xxx {key2}'` -- nice for generating texts from templates. There is also the older `string_template % dictionary`. But the templates do not look that clean: `'ssss %(key1)s xxx %(key2)s'`.

Comment: FYI, as of Python 3.6, we get [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/), so you can now also do `print(f"Total score for {name} is {score}")` with no explicit function calls (as long as `name` and `score` are in scope obviously).

Comment: @SnakesandCoffee Why is `print("Total score for "+str(name)"+ is "+str(score))` disapproved?

Comment: @SnakesandCoffee Lol...got the answer...some other guy also had the same question...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41008941/why-is-printtext-strvar1-more-text-strvar2-described-as-disappr

Comment: Is there one that is common for Python 2 and Python 3 ?

Answer (score 64):

There are many ways to print that.

Let's have a look with another example.

```
a = 10
b = 20
c = a + b

#Normal string concatenation
print("sum of", a , "and" , b , "is" , c) 

#convert variable into str
print("sum of " + str(a) + " and " + str(b) + " is " + str(c)) 

# if you want to print in tuple way
print("Sum of %s and %s is %s: " %(a,b,c))  

#New style string formatting
print("sum of {} and {} is {}".format(a,b,c)) 

#in case you want to use repr()
print("sum of " + repr(a) + " and " + repr(b) + " is " + repr(c))

EDIT :

#New f-string formatting from Python 3.6:
print(f'Sum of {a} and {b} is {c}')
```

Comment: The first comment (`#Normal string concatenation`) is at least misleading.

Comment: Agree @Wolf. sep=" " is the default concatenation, but "normal concatenation" I think would be using print(,sep="").

Answer (score 54):

Use: `.format()`:

```
print("Total score for {0} is {1}".format(name, score))
```

Or:

```
// Recommended, more readable code

print("Total score for {n} is {s}".format(n=name, s=score))
```

Or:

```
print("Total score for" + name + " is " + score)
```

Or:

```
print("Total score for %s is %d" % (name, score))
```

Or:  `f-string` formatting from **Python 3.6**:

```
print(f'Total score for {name} is {score}')
```

Can use `repr` and automatically the `''`   is added:

```
print("Total score for" + repr(name) + " is " + repr(score))

# or for advanced: 
print(f'Total score for {name!r} is {score!r}')
```

Answer (score 23):

In Python 3.6, `f-string` is much cleaner.

In earlier version:

```
print("Total score for %s is %s. " % (name, score))
```

In Python 3.6:

```
print(f'Total score for {name} is {score}.')
```

will do.

It is more efficient and elegant.

Answer (score 15):

Keeping it simple, I personally like string concatenation:

```
print("Total score for " + name + " is " + score)
```

It works with both Python 2.7 an 3.X.

NOTE: If score is an *int*, then, you should convert it to *str*:

```
print("Total score for " + name + " is " + str(score))
```

Answer (score 15):

Just follow this

```
grade = "the biggest idiot"
year = 22
print("I have been {} for {} years.".format(grade, year))
```

**OR**

```
grade = "the biggest idiot"
year = 22
print("I have been %s for %s years." % (grade, year))
```

And forget all others, else the brain won't be able to map all the formats.

Comment: I know this is quite old. But what about the new `f"I have been {a} for {b} years"`? I'm going by only that one recently...

Answer (score 12):

Just try:

```
print("Total score for", name, "is", score)
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `f-string`:

```
print(f'Total score for {name} is {score}')
```

Or

Use `.format`:

```
print("Total score for {} is {}".format(name, score))
```

Comment: When exactly should `.format` be used, now that you have f-strings?

Comment: BTW: when are you using `"` and when `'` quotation?

Answer (score 6):

```
print("Total score for %s is %s  " % (name, score))
```

`%s` can be replace by `%d` or `%f`

Answer (score 5):

If `score` is a number, then

```
print("Total score for %s is %d" % (name, score))
```

If score is a string, then

```
print("Total score for %s is %s" % (name, score))
```

If score is a number, then it's `%d`, if it's a string, then it's `%s`, if score is a float, then it's `%f`

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is as follows

```
print(f"Total score for {name} is {score}")
```

Just put an "f" in front.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I do:

```
print("Total score for " + name + " is " + score)
```

Remember to put a space after `for` and before and after `is`.

Answer (score 0):

This was probably a `casting issue`. `Casting syntax` happens when you try to combine two different `types of variables`. Since we cannot convert a `string` to an `integer` or `float` always, we have to convert our `integers` into a `string`. This is how you do it.: `str(x)`. To convert to a integer, it's: `int(x)`, and a float is `float(x)`. Our code will be:

```
print('Total score for ' + str(name) + ' is ' + str(score))
```

Also! Run this `snippet` to see a table of how to convert different `types of variables`!

```html
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;background-color:maroon; color: #00b2b2;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 50%;font-family: serif; padding: 3px;">Booleans</td>
<td style="width: 50%;font-family: serif; padding: 3px;"><code>bool()</code></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
<td style="width: 50%;font-family: serif;padding: 3px">Dictionaries</td>
<td style="width: 50%;font-family: serif;padding: 3px"><code>dict()</code></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 50%;font-family: serif;padding: 3px">Floats</td>
<td style="width: 50%;font-family: serif;padding: 3px"><code>float()</code></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 50%;font-family: serif;padding:3px">Integers</td>
<td style="width: 50%;font-family: serif;padding:3px;"><code>int()</code></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 50%;font-family: serif;padding: 3px">Lists</td>
<td style="width: 50%font-family: serif;padding: 3px;"><code>list()</code></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
print(f"Total score calculation complete, {name=}, {score=}")
# this will print:
# Total score calculation complete, name='Alice', score=100
```

Note that this prints `name='Alice'`, not just `'Alice'`!

All features:

- You get **variable name** printing along with **variable value**. This is extremely useful for debug printing. If you don't need it for a certain variable, omit the `=` sign.
- If you rename, remove or add any debugged variables, this print line will remain correct
- Don't worry about alignment. If you have multiple variables, is the 4-th argument `score` or `age`? Well, you don't care, it's correct regardless.
- Note that this is only available for Python 3.8+