# Printing int and string in a single expression in python

Tags: python, printing

I want to print few words followed by a int followed by few words again followed by a big int in python. How can we do it... Like in c++, we do:

```
cout<<" "<<x<<" "<y
```

where x and y are integers.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Have you done any [research](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286401/print-multiple-arguments-in-python)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways, just to mention a few:

```
# Python 2.x

print 'before', 42, 'after'
print 'before ' + str(42) + ' after'
print '%s %d %s' % ('before', 42, 'after')  # deprecated
print '{} {} {}'.format('before', 42, 'after')

# Python 3.x

print('before', 42, 'after', sep=' ')
print('before ' + str(42) + ' after')
print('%s %d %s' % ('before', 42, 'after')) # deprecated
print('{} {} {}'.format('before', 42, 'after'))
```

All of the above statements will produce the same result on-screen:

```
=> before 42 after
```

Comment: print "some words", 42, "more words"

Comment: I would use the more general `repr` instead of `str`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
print 'word %s word word' % 42
```

Comment: @John Kugelman, check my edit

Answer (score 0):

Something closer to C

```
i = 34
x = 56
print "Integer i = %d and integer x = %d" % (i,x)
```