# Multiple Arguments in an Input?

Tags: python-3.x, printing, arguments

Beginner Programmer here. I'm trying to write a program that will ask a user for a quiz grade until they enter a blank input. Also, I'm trying to get the input to go from displaying "quiz1: " to "quiz2: ", "quiz3: ", and so on each time the user enters a new quiz grade. Like so:

```
quiz1: 10 
quiz2: 11
quiz3: 12
```

Here's what I've written so far:

```
grade = input ("quiz1: ")
count = 0
while grade != "" :
    count += 1
    grade = input ("quiz ", count, ": ")
```

I've successfully managed to make my program end when a blank value is entered into the input, but when I try to enter an integer for a quiz grade I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\test script.py", line 5, in <module>
    grade = input ("quiz ", count, ": ")
TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3
```

How do I include more than one argument inside the parenthesis associated with the **grade** input?

Comment: What do you want to do with the grades? Depending on the intent, you could build a dictionary of grades, or build a list. Either way, you'd be able to access individual scores, as well as determine mean (and other values).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print multiple arguments in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286401/print-multiple-arguments-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `input` function only accepts one argument, being the message. However to get around it, one option would be to use a print statement before with an empty ending character like so:

```
.
.
.
while grade != "":
    count += 1
    print("quiz ", count,": ", end="")
    grade = input()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.format`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format), e.g.:

```
count = 0
while grade != "" :
    count += 1
    grade = input('quiz {}:'.format(count))
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it is easy to make the variable within the str () function to convert it from a number to a string and to separate all the arguments using "+" and do not use "-" where programmatically when using "+" Python will be considered as one string

```
grade = input ("quiz 1: ")
count = 1
while grade != "" :
    count += 1
    grade = input ("quiz "+ str(count) + ": ")
```