# Python - Shorter way to print these variables

Tags: python

If I have five variables - each named var0, var1, var2, var3, var4 is there a shorter way to print these than typing out print(var0), print(var1) etc. for each one? Perhaps a for loop? Somewhat new to python. I have something I'm trying to create. If this is possible it should get me where I need to be.

Edit: They are dynamic variables, so none of those solutions would work. It could be var1-5 or var1-25.

Comment: Yep there is: `print(var1, var2, var3, var4, sep='\n')`.

Comment: Have you heard of lists?

Comment: @leaf please do not post answers as comments.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have those variables in a list? In which case to print them out in a single liner would be trivial, as well as lots of other things, probably.

Comment: @MoonCheesez it is absolutely ok to post an answer as a comment

Comment: If they all the same kind of thing (homogeneous), keep them in a list. If they all different kinds of things (heterogeneous), keep them in a namedtuple.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print multiple arguments in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286401/print-multiple-arguments-in-python)

Comment: Well, they're dynamic variables, so it could be 1-5 or 1-10 or however many so that wouldn't work, and i start with a list that I'm splitting into separate strings.

Comment: @MoonCheesez Why not? I  really don't think my previous comment would work well as an answer.

Comment: @leaf It is a common problem that questions are resolved in the comments but the question does not have an answer. (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253045/answerers-who-only-use-comments and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) however, it could be the case where you did not have time to create a full answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4217/why-do-some-people-answer-in-comments

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of values you can join them together with a separator.

```
>>> print('\n'.join(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
a
b
c
d
```

Answer (score 1):

The new `print()` function in Python 3.x takes a `sep` keyword argument which is used to separate the contents passed to `print()`. This can be used to separate the output of each of your variables by newlines - as if they were being printed separately:

```
>>> var1, var2, var3, var4 = 1, 2, 3, 4
>>> print(var1, var2, var3, var4, sep='\n')
1
2
3
4
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do `print(var1, var2, var3, var 4, sep='\n')`. It should print them out with a blank line inbetween.

Comment: What version of Python?

Comment: @PeterWood Um... 3.x? I'm not sure where your getting at.

Comment: It's worth qualifying with the version as it doesn't work with Python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

This command will work without change, even if you have `var1` up to `var99999`.

```
import re
print(["{} = {}".format(v, eval(v)) for v in dir() if re.match('var.*', v)])
```