# How to print a C format in python

Tags: python, printf, string-formatting

A python newbie question:

I would like to print in python with the c format with a list of parameters:

```
agrs = [1,2,3,"hello"]
string = "This is a test %d, %d, %d, %s"
```

How can I print using python as:

**This is a test 1, 2, 3, hello**

Thanks.

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286401/print-multiple-arguments-in-python

Comment: I'd say go look here in the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html Everything is very well documented there and it should be the first place you look.

Comment: @bouletta: I wouldn't call it a duplicate only because this specific question is concerned with formatting an existing `list` as sequential format items. True, you could just blindly do `string % (agrs[0], agrs[1], agrs[2], agrs[3])` and it would work, but you wouldn't necessarily understand why it worked (that you need a `tuple` specifically, and `list(agrs)` works just fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strings overload the modulus operator, `%`, for [`printf`-style formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting), and special case `tuple`s for formatting using multiple values, so all you need to do is convert from `list` to `tuple`:

```
print(string % tuple(agrs))
```

Comment: This works well for me and is simplest way.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

**Tuple:**

Example:

```
print("Total score for %s is %s  " % (name, score))
```

In your case:

```
print(string % tuple(agrs))
```

**Or use the new-style string formatting:**

```
print("Total score for {} is {}".format(name, score))
```

**Or pass the values as parameters and print will do it:**

```
print("Total score for", name, "is", score)
```

---

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286401/print-multiple-arguments-in-python)

Comment: @ShadowRanger method work best for me because the agrs list is a variable list of parameter.  the "string" is a predefine format so changing it is just making it more complicated.  Thanks Liam.

Answer (score 1):

Using new-style formatting: How about these one?  (just experementing here)
Docs: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html

```
args = [1,2,3,"hello"]
string = "{}, "*(len(args)-1)+"{}" # = "{}, {}, {}, {}"

'This is a test {}'.format(string.format(*args)) # inception!
```

Or this one:

```
args = [1,2,3,"hello"]
argstring = [str(i) for i in args]
'This is a test {}'.format(', '.join(argstring))
```

Or simply:

```
args = [1,2,3,"hello"]
'This is a test {}'.format(', '.join(map(str,args)))
```

All print:

> This is a test 1, 2, 3, hello

Answer (score 1):

The % character is not needed in following method:

```
agrs = [1,2,3,"hello"]
print("This is a test: {:02d},{:>10d},{:05d},{:>15s}".format(agrs[0],agrs[1],agrs[2],agrs[3]))
```

Same will do:

```
agrs = [1,2,3,"hello"]
print("This is a test: {0:02d},{1:>10d},{2:05d},{3:>15s}".format(agrs[0],agrs[1],agrs[2],agrs[3]))
```

Each item is formatted by what follows ":" within each curly bracket, and each of those corresponds to an argument passed on in brackets to format. For example, agrs[0] is passed and the format is "02d", which is equivalent of %02d in C.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `%` operator. It accepts a string and a tuple like that:

```
print "My age is %d and my favourite char is %c" % (16, '$')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
l = [1,2,3,"hello"]
print("This is a test %d, %d, %d, %s"%(l[0],l[1],l[2],l[3]))
```

Hope this works !
Cheers bud!