# Python integer spacing

Tags: python

I have a code like this.

```
print (' ', totalh, totalt, totalo)
```

and I want the integer of `totalh` to be  `2 2` instead of `22` with a space in-between the integers. How do I go about doing it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print multiple arguments in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286401/print-multiple-arguments-in-python)

Answer (score 4):

Convert it to a string which is an iterable and can be an argument to `" ".join`.

```
totalh = 22
print(" ".join(str(totalh)))
```

Output:

```
2 2
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you this simple way: first convert `totalh` into a string with each digit being a character, then use `" ".join()` to insert a space between each digit:

```
totalh = 22
print(" ".join(str(totalh))) #2 2
```