# print function seems to ignore parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the following lines of code, the print function seems to ignore the parameter hint I created earlier and want to refer to now. 
Can someone give me a hint on why?

```
print("Ah I see, you're stuck. \n"
              "Have a hint.\n"
              "The first three letters are", hint, ".")
```

hint being a parameter (unsure whether that is the correct name of that) I defined as following: hint = word[0:3], with word being a tuple. Is that maybe the mistake, that I need to refer hint in a tuple like referring manner? Edit: I tried to refer to as "The first three letters are %s." % (hint) as suggested in the linked article and it still does not work.

The output stays

> Ah I see, you're stuck. 
>   Have a hint.
>   The first three letters are .

I tried many ways, I found on here in this article ([article on printing referred parameters, tuples and such.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286401/print-multiple-arguments-in-python))

Sorry for this simple question, I am just starting out and unfortunately I already mess up this easy stuff.

Comment: what is `hint`?

Comment: a variable I defined as following: hint = word[0:3], with word being a tuple. Is that maybe the mistake, that I need to refer hint in a tuple like referring manner?
Edit: I tried to refer to as "The first three letters are %s." % (hint) as suggested in the linked article and it still does not work.

Comment: Add all that relevant information to your question, clearly state what you get and what you want to get. read [ask] and improve your question

Comment: You can use `'''` for multiple line string

Comment: Edit your question to include the exact definition of `hint`, and the exact output you get from the print.

Comment: [this](https://gist.github.com/dumbledad/bf1e4e59c87ea261182059a9d0c7d0a9) seems to work fine for me

Comment: @JohnGordon done.

Comment: @dumbledad what? how can that be?

Comment: We need to see the line where you define `word` and I would include the line where you define `hint` too as @JohnGordon requested

Comment: With that output, `hint` must be an empty string.  It sure would help if you'd show us how `hint` is defined...

Comment: Even tho it work for me but this: `print("Ah I see, you're stuck. \nHave a hint.\nThe first three letters are", hint, ".")`