# How can I name a image including more than one index (using pt.savefig)?

Tags: python, image, file, indexing

I'm trying to save a lot of images. I have them codified as arrays and I realized that even though at the beginning the saving goes very fast it starts to get very slow when I have saved some of them. I found a solution to that by changing the name of the file I'm saving but don't know how to include two indexes in the file name. 
What I'm doing is this.

```
pt.savefig("Prueba%s.png"%i)
```

And when I try to do:

```
pt.savefig("%s.Prueba%s.png"%j, %i)
```

it says that I'm having a sintax error. I'm very new with python and I have tried many different things but nothing worked. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print multiple arguments in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286401/print-multiple-arguments-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the format.

> pt.savefig("{}.Prueba{}.png".format(j, i))