# Python printing spaces, fizz buzz

Tags: python, indentation

I wrote the code for a fizz buzz game, where it prints fizz for multiples of 3 and buzz for multiples of 5. Then fizz buzz for both everything works but the output. Its supposed to print
1:
2:
3: fizz

and so on but mine prints an extra space

1 :
2 :
3 : fizz

I provided the code below thanks for any help

```
def fizzbuzz(n):
  for num in range(1,n+1):
    if num % 3 == 0 and num % 5 == 0:
      print(num,': FizzBuzz')
    elif num % 3 == 0:
      print(num,": Fizz")
    elif num % 5 ==0:
      print(num,": Buzz")
    else:
      print(num,":")




fizzbuzz(n=21)
```

Comment: `print` adds a whitespace between the arguments it receives. Use string interpolation

Comment: What @DeepSpace said. https://pyformat.info/ provides a good documentation.

Comment: Lots of answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286401/print-multiple-arguments-in-python

Comment: Read the docs on [print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print), you can change the ``sep=' '`` argument

Answer (score 0):

Probably `f strings` could work, but it only works for `python 3.6` and above of it.

```
def fizzbuzz(n):
  for num in range(1,n+1):
    if num % 3 == 0 and num % 5 == 0:
      print(f'{num} FizzBuzz')
    elif num % 3 == 0:
      print(f'{num} Fizz')
    elif num % 5 ==0:
      print(f'{num} Buzz')
    else:
      print(f'{num}:')
      
fizzbuzz(n=21)
```