# How to solve unsupported operand types

Tags: python-3.x

am trying to print some new from the API but I
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
print(str(i)+'. '+item['title']+'\n')

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286401/print-multiple-arguments-in-python

Comment: This means exactly what it is. You cannot concatenate the values of `item['title']` with a string

Comment: Assuming that `item["title"]` could return `None` (hence your error), what would you like to have printed? Slapping a `str()` around it gets rid of the error, but now your result will contain the word "None" as `str(None) == "None"`. If that is what you want, great. I suspect though that in the event `item["title"] is None` perhaps the entire print statement should be avoided. In that case, your real issue is that you should be checking for that use case and handling it. You may also want to check out : `print(str(i) + ". " + (item['title'] or "_title_not_defined_") + "\n")`

Answer (score 0):

In your line of code `print(str(i)+'. '+item['title']+'\n')` I am thinking that your `item['title']` is returning a `None`, and python doesn't know how to add a `str` to a `None`.  Try adding a `str()` around your `item['title']` and see if it works then.