# How can I combine these two lines?

Tags: python-3.x

How can I combine these two lines so the output shows both results next to each other instead of on separate lines? I've tried multiple things but can't get it to work.

```py
print(data.get('unit').get('type'))
print(data.get('unit').get('name'))
```

If I do:

```py
print(data.get('unit').get('type'), data.get('unit').get('name'))
```

it will only return one value either type or name

Comment: `print(data.get('unit').get('type'), data.get('unit').get('name'))`?

Comment: Does [How to print without a newline or space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-a-newline-or-space) help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print without a newline or space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-a-newline-or-space)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print multiple arguments in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286401/print-multiple-arguments-in-python)