# Same line typing numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know how to type numbers from python.

```
>>> for  a in range(1,11):
     print(a)

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Here the output is given in one line after the other.
So I want to type the numbers in the same line without using lists and stacks. I that possible?
Then how can I do that?

Comment: Possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598181/python-print-on-same-line

Answer (score 3):

[print](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#print) automatically adds a newline character after the string you've entered, this is why it prints each number on a different line. To change this behavior, you must change `end` parameter on the function call.

```
for a in range(1,11):
    print(a, end=' ')
```

---

**Edit:**
The `end` parameter holds a string which gets printed after the string you've entered. By default it's set to `\n` so after each print, `\n` is added:

```
print("Hello!") # actually prints "Hello!\n"
```

You can change the parameter to anything you like:

```
print("Hello!", end="...") # prints "Hello!..."
print("Hello!", end="") # prints "Hello!"
```

Comment: Thanks for th answer.It seems as an easy way which does my job.Actually what does end do here?I'm a beginner to Python..

Comment: @SasankaWeerathunge It defines what to print after the actual string you entered. See my latest edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> print(' '.join(str(i) for i in range(1,11)))
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```