# How to print output of for loop on same line

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
def missing_ch(number, string):
      for i in range(len(string)):
        if i==number:
           continue
        else:   
           print(string[i], end=' ')
      return
string='hello'
num=int(input("enter the position of char"))
missing_ch(num, string)
```

How to get output characters printed in same line?

Comment: ... on the same line with what?

Comment: What's the error you get ? I'm willing to bet that your code doesn't work because of syntax errors ... did you read the console output ?

Comment: `print(item, end=" ")` is sufficient

Comment: `if(ch==num)`  variable `ch` doesn't declared in your function... also there are a lot of mistakes to remove: `(int)()`=`int()`, `if()`=just `if`, `range(len(str)`=`range(len(str))`

Comment: I did a mistake in writing but my code was right I checked it with console output

Comment: I was getting out put on new line but I want to make it on same line

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python print on same line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598181/python-print-on-same-line)

Answer (score 0):

I see 3 issues in your program -

1. In the `for` loop in second line , you have missed closing a bracket - `for i in range (len(str):` , it should be - `for i in range (len(str)):`
2. There is no `casting` in python, to convert  input to string, you have use `int` function, as `int(...)` , so your line `(int)(input(...))` should be - `int(input(...))` .
3. In your for loop, you are defining the index as `i`, but you are using `ch` inside the loop, you should be using `i` instead of `ch.

Example -

```
    for i in range (len(str):
        if(i==num):
            continue
        print(str[i],end=' ')
    return
```

The print statement to print items without appending the newline is fine, it should be working.

A working example -

```
>>> def foo():
...     print("Hello",end=" ")
...     print("Middle",end=" ")
...     print("Bye")
...
>>> foo()
Hello Middle Bye
```

Answer (score 0):

To print on one line, you could append each letter on a string.

```
def missing_ch(num, str):
  result = ""
  for i in range (len(str)):
    if (i == num):
      continue
    result+=str[i]
  print result

string = 'hello'
num = (int)(input('enter the position of char'))

missing_ch(num, string)
```

`#>helo`

Answer (score -1):

I'm new into python and my friend is giving me tasks to perform and one of them was to print a square made out of "*" and this is how I did it:

```
br = int(input("Enter a number: "))

for i in range(0, br):
    print("*" * br)
```