# How to print out n (3) items from a list at a time and then display them on one line. Python 3

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

As you can see from the code below, I have my program read text from a text file (homework.txt) to a list called heightandweight. I then have it print 3 items in the list at a time. However it doesn't print the 3 pieces of information on one line. How would I do that?

```
myFile = open("homework.txt","rt")
heightandweight = []

for line in myFile:
    line = line.strip("\n")
    heightandweight.append(line)

print(heightandweight)
myFile.close()

for e in range (0, len(heightandweight),3):
    for i in heightandweight[e:e+3]:
        print (i)
```

The above code will output:

```
['James', '73', '1.82', 'Peter', '78', '1.80', 'Jay', 'Beth', '65', '1.53', 'Mags', '66', '1.50', 'Joy', '62', '1.34']
James
73
1.82
Peter
78
1.80
Jay
Beth
65
1.53
Mags
66
1.50
Joy
62
1.34
```

Comment: Is Jay supposed to have a height and weight or should your code be able to cope with the case where they are missing?

Comment: Similar question has been answered [here][1].



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598181/python-print-on-same-line

Comment: Thank you! How would I work out the average height and average weight of all of the people? The height in this list is the 2 digit whole number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use format strings (i.e. if you just want to print out a set of data without having a newline) then you can prevent a newline by using:

```
print data,
```

or, if you're using Python 3:

```
print(data, end="")
```

Assuming the latter, your code would then look like:

```
for e in range (0, len(heightandweight),3):
    for i in heightandweight[e:e+3]:
        print(i, end="")
    print("")
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to learn about [formatting strings](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/string.html#format-examples) in python. In your case the relevant code would be something like:

```
for e in range (0, len(heightandweight),3):
    string="{} {} {}".format(heightandweight[e], heightandweight[e+1], heightandweight[e+2])
    print(string)
```

Which could be compressed into just:

```
for e in range (0, len(heightandweight),3):
    print("{} {} {}".format(heightandweight[e], heightandweight[e+1], heightandweight[e+2]))
```

However it would be much neater to have the original text file be organised like this in columns:

```
James 73 1.82
Peter 78 1.80
Beth 65 1.53
Mags 66 1.50
Joy 62 1.34
```

Then your code could be simplified to:

```
with open("homework.txt","rt") as myFile:
    for line in myFile:
        name, height, weight = line.split(' ')
        print("{} {} {}".format(name, height, weight))
```

Comment: I think the last solution is the proper one

Answer (score 0):

With python it is very easy. I recommend you strongly to check the function join (https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

I am not sure if this is why you want but you can test this :

```
for e in range (0, len(heightandweight),3):
    print(" ".join(heightandweight[e:e+3]))
```

Answer (score 0):

simple iterator:

```
lst=['James', '73', '1.82', 'Peter', '78', '1.80', 'Jay', 'Beth', '65', '1.53', 'Mags', '66', '1.50', 'Joy', '62', '1.34']
lst_copy=lst #if You need to use oryginal lst later use it, otherwise dont
for i in range(len(lst)):
    try:lst[i]=float(lst[i])
    except:pass
for i in range(0,len(lst),3):
    try:
        if type(lst_copy[i+1])!=float:
            print(lst_copy[i])
            lst_copy.pop(i)
        else:
            print(i,lst_copy[i:i+3])
    except:pass
```