# how to simply code and code repetiveness for dictionary problem

Tags: python, dictionary, while-loop

I am new to programming, and I am trying to trying to solve this for my assignment(instructions below), but I have  few quick questions:

1. is there any way to simply or condense some of these lines, i feel like I am rendundantly printing when I dont know if there is another way I can have it all in one print line, for instance:

```
print ("which state capitals do you want to know: ")
print (list(state_dictionary.keys()))
```

is there a way that can be one print statement?

```
def state_capitals():
    state_dictionary= {"New Hampshire":"Concord", "Massachusetts": "Boston", "Maine": "Albany", 
                         "Vermont": "M", "New York": "Albany"}
       i=0
       while i <= (len(state_dictionary)):
           print ("which state capitals do you want to know: ")
           print (list(state_dictionary.keys()))

           getcapital= input("enter state: ")
           print(state_dictionary[getcapital])

           state_dictionary.pop(getcapital)

           more= (input("Do you want to know the capital of any more states? Please enter Yes/No: "))

           if more == "yes":
               if bool(state_dictionary):
                   continue

               elif not bool (state_dictionary):
                   print ("i am out of states")
                   break

           elif more == "no":
               break


   state_capitals()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print out n (3) items from a list at a time and then display them on one line. Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32295763/how-to-print-out-n-3-items-from-a-list-at-a-time-and-then-display-them-on-one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the print statements go, you can check out f-strings:

```py
somedict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}

print(f"My dictionary is {somedict}")
My dictionary is {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

or `str.format`:

```py
print("My dictionary is {}".format(somedict))
```

The call to `list(state_dictionary.keys())` is redundant, `list` will just consume the keys, so it should be `list(state_dictionary)`

You don't need `bool` to wrap your `state_dictionary`, as dict has a built in `__bool__` implementation that is invoked when you call `if state_dictionary`.

`dict.pop` on a missing key will raise a `KeyError`, so catch it in case someone gives you an input you don't expect:

```py
try:
    state_dictionary.pop(getcapital)
except KeyError as e:
    print("Sorry, I don't have that state! Try again")
    continue
```

You also don't need the `if i <= len(dict)` for your while loop. You *could* do a `while state_dictionary` statement, but you check that condition in the loop, so I'd just do a `while True` and let your contained conditional logic handle the rest.

I'd change the `elif more == 'no'` to `else`, if the user doesn't give you valid input, then you can just end the execution. Since you prompt the user with `Yes` and `No`, rather than `yes` and `no`, I'd sanitize the input like:

```py
more = more.lower().strip()
```

This will lowercase everything and get rid of extra newlines/spaces that might be accidentally entered