# Code implementing Pascal's triangle code using binomials

Tags: python

I am having trouble getting this Python code to work right. It is code to display [Pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle) using binomials. I do not know what is wrong. The code looks like this:

```
from math import factorial

def binomial(n, k):
    if k == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return int((factorial(n)//factorial(k))*factorial(n-k))

def pascals_triangle(rows):
    rows = 20
    for n in range (0, rows):
        for k in range (0, n+1):
            print(binomial(n, k))
    print '\n'
```

This is what it keeps printing

```
1
1
1
1
2
1
1
12
3
1
1
144
24
4
1
1
2880
360
40
5
1
1
86400
8640
720
60
6
1
1
3628800
302400
20160
1260
```

And on and on. How can I fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598181/python-print-on-same-line

Comment: Something like that: `print(binomial(n,k), end = " ")`

Comment: First of all: What is the expected result? Please edit your question to reflect the desired output. While Pascal's triangle looks easy on paper, there are many ways to print it on a console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
from math import factorial

def binomial (n, k):
    if k == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return int((factorial(n)//factorial(k))*factorial(n-k))

def pascals_triangle(rows):
    for n in range (rows):
        l = [binomial(n, k) for k in range (0, n+1)]
        print l

pascals_triangle(5)
```

#### Output

```
    [1]
    [1, 1]
    [1, 2, 1]
    [1, 12, 3, 1]
    [1, 144, 24, 4, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many wrong things.
The first one is the way you compute the values: if building a Pascal's triangle, you want to use the previous line to compute the current one, and not use the binomial computation (which is expensive due to the number of multiplications).

Then by default, `print` appends a "\n"

Correct implementation:

```
def print_line(x):
    print (" ".join(map(str, x)))

def pascals_triangle(rows):
    cur_line = [1, 1]
    for x in range (2, rows):
        new_line = [1]
        for n in range (0, len(cur_line)-1):
            new_line.append(cur_line[n] + cur_line[n+1])
        new_line.append(1)
        print_line (new_line)
        cur_line = new_line
```

This provides the following output:

```
python pascal.py
```

Output:

```
1 2 1
1 3 3 1
1 4 6 4 1
1 5 10 10 5 1
1 6 15 20 15 6 1
1 7 21 35 35 21 7 1
1 8 28 56 70 56 28 8 1
1 9 36 84 126 126 84 36 9 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your binomial function had a small bracketing mistake in it, which was giving you incorrect output:

```
from math import factorial

def binomial(n, k):
    if k==0:
        return 1
    else:
        return int((factorial(n)/(factorial(k)*factorial(n-k))))

def pascals_triangle(rows, max_width):
    for n in range (0,rows):
        indent = (rows - n - 1) * max_width
        print(' ' * indent, end='')
        for k in range(0, n+1):
            print("{:^{w}}".format(binomial(n, k), w = max_width*2), end='')
        print()

pascals_triangle(7, 2)
```

With the addition of a padding parameter, the output can be made to look like this:

```
             1
           1   1
         1   2   1
       1   3   3   1
     1   4   6   4   1
   1   5   10  10  5   1
 1   6   15  20  15  6   1
```