# how can I append the values of the print function in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, append

this is what the print function gives me

```
/home/codes/paths/0000001090.png
/home/codes/paths/0000001091.png
/home/codes/paths/0000001092.png
/home/codes/paths/0000001093.png
```

I want to have it like

```
[/home/codes/paths/0000001090.png
/home/codes/paths/0000001091.png
/home/codes/paths/0000001092.png
/home/codes/paths/0000001093.png]
```

so I tried use list.append

```
raw_image_path= image_path+str(image_id).zfill(10)+'.png'
all_images = []   
all_images.append(raw_image_path)
print (all_images)
```

but it seems to append every printed value separately

```
    [/home/codes/paths/0000001090.png]
    [/home/codes/paths/0000001091.png]
    [/home/codes/paths/0000001092.png]
    [/home/codes/paths/0000001093.png]
```

how can I solve this ?

Comment: to print something without going to next line do `print "[",` with trailing comma to continue printing on same line (in python 3 you'd do `print("[", end="")`)

Comment: will refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598181/python-print-on-same-line) as closely related and will likely solve your issue.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have a loop and are creating and printing a new list every single iteration.

```
for ...:
    raw_image_path= image_path+str(image_id).zfill(10)+'.png'
    all_images = []   # new list
    all_images.append(raw_image_path)
    print (all_images) # printing a single list
# 'len(all_images) == 1' here
```

Options:

1) Move `all_images` outside, before the loop, and append inside, then print outside, after

2) Try list comprehension instead.

```
In [1]: all_images = [ "{}{}.png".format('/', str(image_id).zfill(10)) for image_id in range(1090, 1095) ]

In [2]: all_images
Out[2]:
['/0000001090.png',
 '/0000001091.png',
 '/0000001092.png',
 '/0000001093.png',
 '/0000001094.png']
```