# How to make no line break in python?

Tags: python

I am using a for loop and it requires me to print something. Each time it prints I dont want the output to be on a seperate line. How do I do this?

```
def getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
  for i in secretWord:
    if (i in lettersGuessed):
      print(i)
    else:
      print ("_")
```

This code is for a hangman game
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python print on same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598181/python-print-on-same-line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prevent printing on a separate line by adding

```
, end=""
```

at the end of the print() function, as in:

```
def getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
    for i in secretWord:
        if (i in lettersGuessed):
            print(i, end="")     # end
        else:
            print ("_", end="")  # end
    print()

# Test
getGuessedWord("HELLO",['A','B','E','H'])
```

which returns:

```
HE___
```