# Why does an in-loop print() output after the loop is completed?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the code below, the diamond characters (`\4`) are not printed immediately but after the loop is completed. Any ideas why?

```
from os import system
from time import sleep

def load():
    system('cls')
    i = 0
    sleep(1)
    print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t Loading ", end=' ')
    for i in range(6):
        sleep(1)
        print("\4", end=' ')
        sleep(2) 
load()
```

Comment: Could not reproduce in Python 2 (using `from __future__ import print_function`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The printing is working in Python IDLE for me. In Windows `cmd` it does not. Removing the `end=' '` solves this, but then each diamond gets printed on a new line.

Depending on your OS you have to change the line ending. 
Check this page for more info on that:  [Python print on same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598181/python-print-on-same-line)

---

This is working on Windows:

```
from os import system
from time import sleep
import sys

def load():
    system('cls')
    i = 0
    sleep(1)
    sys.stdout.write("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t Loading ")
    for i in range(6):
        sleep(1)
        sys.stdout.write("\4")
        sys.stdout.flush()
        sleep(2)

load()
```