# How to create the character patterns in python 3 using stars and dots?

Tags: python-3.x

I am solving the character pattern (Act 1) challenge in **Python 3** on SPOJ. I am getting the output but it is not related to sample output.Please check my code for reference:

```
# your code goes here
n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    s,t = input().split()
    s,t = int(s),int(t)
    for i in range(s):
        for j in range(t):
            if (i+j) % 2 == 0:
                print("*")
            else:
                print(".")
    print("\n")
```

I got the following output:

```
*
.
*


*
.
*
.
.
*
.
*
*
.
*
.
.
*
.
*


*
.
*
.
*
.
*
.
*
.
```

but the correct output is:

```
*
.
*

*.*.
.*.*
*.*.
.*.*

*.*.*
.*.*.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: multiple prints on the same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598181/python-multiple-prints-on-the-same-line)

Comment: No Sir I didn't want you to solve this problem but I want to know where I am going wrong.Why my pattern is not matching with the sample output

Answer (score 0):

In **Python 3** to print something without new line at the end you need to use the following syntax:

```
print(something, end="")
```

Comment: that's because your code logic is wrong, but no one will help you with that... it would be cheating

Comment: look at the problem this way: it's only about making a function that will add another `.` or another `*` to the chain and print it in loop every time it will be added

Comment: Sir I think you didn't understand my problem.I am asking for some code that will give me the desired output.

Comment: But no one gonna give you the code, as it would be cheating. I said that before. Sorry!