# Why does time.sleep() happen all at once instead of one at a time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, python-3.6, sleep

I'm trying to make a little animation type thing where it prints R then waits for .5 seconds the o then waits for .5 seconds and so on until the end.
Here is the code I wrote:

```
import time
def rolling():
    print('R', end = '')
    time.sleep(.5)
    print('o', end = '')
    time.sleep(.5)
    print('l', end = '')
    time.sleep(.5)
    print('l', end = '')
    time.sleep(.5)
    print('i', end = '')
    time.sleep(.5)
    print('n', end = '')
    time.sleep(.5)
    print('g', end = '')
    time.sleep(.5)
```

When I run that it waits for 3.5 seconds and then prints the whole word. Any suggestions?

Comment: stdout is buffered; see https://eklitzke.org/stdout-buffering for some details on this topic.

Comment: You got me curious, so I googled. add ```flush=True``` arg to each ```print``` and it does what you want, ie. ```print('R', end = '', flush=True)```. Found answer on SO here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598181/multiple-prints-on-the-same-line-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of your program is line buffered (as is in any common scenario), therefore, since you are not printing any newline (`\n`), the result is only written to the console at the end of execution, all at once.

To ensure each call to `print()` immediately produces an output, you can add `flush=True` (thank you [pink spikyhairman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5444173/pink-spikyhairman) for pointing this out, I was unaware of the feature at the time of writing the original answer):

```
import time

def rolling():
    print('R', end = '', flush=True)
    time.sleep(.5)
    print('o', end = '', flush=True)
    time.sleep(.5)
```

You could even directly go with `sys.stdout.write()` and `.flush()` instead:

```
import time
import sys

def rolling():
    sys.stdout.write('R')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(.5)
    sys.stdout.write('R')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(.5)
    # ...
```