# Getting multiple if statements to print on a single line

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

I am trying to pull words and integers from a text file and have them all print on the same line using if statements. Would I need to continue with the for loop to achieve the outputs to be printed on the same line?

I am trying to get it print frame #, type:0x0800

```
with open('wireShark.txt', 'rt') as file_content:
for line in file_content:
    if 'Frame' in line:
        i=line.find(':') 
        idnum = line[0:i] 
        print(idnum)

    if 'Type' in line:
        i=line.find(':')
        idnum4 = line[4:9]
        print (idnum4)

    if '0x0800' in line:
        i=line.find(')')
        idnum5 = line[16:i]
        print (idnum5)
```

Comment: what is your input and desired output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [multiple prints on the same line in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598181/multiple-prints-on-the-same-line-in-python)

Comment: The `for` block is not properly indented within the `with` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As many people are noticing, you don't need to print with a new line.

```
with open('wireShark.txt', 'rt') as file_content:
for line in file_content:
    if 'Frame' in line:
        i=line.find(':') 
        idnum = line[0:i] 
        print(idnum, end="")

    if 'Type' in line:
        i=line.find(':')
        idnum4 = line[4:9]
        print (idnum4, end="")

    if '0x0800' in line:
        i=line.find(')')
        idnum5 = line[16:i]
        print (idnum5, end="")
```

The `end=""` just tells Python: Hey, don't print a newline.

Comment: Yes, it's because you're using Python 2. Please *don't* use Python 2.

Comment: got it! How would i go about in breaking the line for multiple lines per frame?

Comment: @justinlandolt what do you mean breaking the line for multiple lines per frame?