# I'm new to python and I am trying to figure out how to print letters one at a time on the same line

Tags: python, wait

This isn't my actual code but it is just an example. How do I make it my code wait but stay on the same line?

```
    import pygame
    pygame.init()

    print("Hi")
    pygame.time.wait(1000)
    print(".")
    pygame.time.wait(500)
    print(".")
    pygame.time.wait(500)
    print(".")
```

Comment: Wait for user's input or simply during execution?

Comment: `print(".", end="")` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [multiple prints on the same line in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598181/multiple-prints-on-the-same-line-in-python)

Comment: do you really need `pygame` for this? Why not `time.sleep`?. And if you write game in `PyGame` then using `wait` is not good idea if you run `event loop` to get key/mouse events.

Answer (score 2):

The default end to a print() statement in python is '\n' (new line). As @sj95126 mentions in his comment, you will want to replace this ending with an empty string. Fortunately, Python gives a simple way of doing this:

```
print("Hi", end="")
pygame.time.wait(1000)
print(".", end="")
pygame.time.wait(500)
print(".", end="")
pygame.time.wait(500)
print(".")
```

The above code will print:

> Hi...

Similarly, if you wanted to make every line end in a comma, you could do:

```
print("A", end=",")
pygame.time.wait(1000)
print("B", end=",")
pygame.time.wait(500)
print("C", end=",")
pygame.time.wait(500)
print("Bye")
```

Which would print:

> A,B,C,Bye