# Putting print statements on the same line

Tags: python, replit

I am tring to learn python and want to know if i can do this, and how. I am trying to make binary looking code come up digit by digit, with delay.
In maybe there is 15 numbers, and each repeat i would like to make it do a set of 5, with a space after.

```
if answer == 'MAYBE':
    deleteall()
    print("GIVE ME AN ANSWER!!!")
    time.sleep(1)
    deletelastline()
    for x in maybe:
      print(random.choice("1" "0"))
      time.sleep(0.1)
      print(random.choice("1" "0"))
      time.sleep(0.1)
      print(random.choice("1" "0"))
      time.sleep(0.1)
      print(random.choice("1" "0"))
      time.sleep(0.1)
      print(random.choice("1" "0"))
      time.sleep(0.1)
      print(" ")
```

However, it outputs this:

```
0
1
1
0
0

1
0
0
0
1

1
```

ext.

How do i get them on one line?!?
Thx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [multiple prints on the same line in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598181/multiple-prints-on-the-same-line-in-python), You know it's not forbidden to enter `[python] print same line` into the serach before posting a question about printing on the same line.

Comment: Unrelated; `"1" "0"` is equivalent to `"10"`, and strings are iterable, which is why your quasi-list argument works. `random.choice(["1", "0"])` would more clearly indicate what you are trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

by setting end parameter you can set whatever will be after it printed. it is next line command by default "\n" so everytime it prints it gets to the next line

```
import time
import random
maybe = range(5)
print("GIVE ME AN ANSWER!!!")
time.sleep(1)
for x in maybe:
    print(random.choice("1" "0"),end=" ")
    time.sleep(0.1)
    print(random.choice("1" "0"),end=" ")
    time.sleep(0.1)
    print(random.choice("1" "0"),end=" ")
    time.sleep(0.1)
    print(random.choice("1" "0"),end=" ")
    time.sleep(0.1)
    print(random.choice("1" "0"),end=" ")
    time.sleep(0.1)
    print(" ")
```

output is:

```
1 1 0 1 1  
0 1 1 1 0  
0 1 0 1 0  
1 0 0 1 0  
1 0 0 0 1
```

Comment: Is there a way to have
01001 01110 11000 11110 00101 ext.

Comment: print(random.choice("1" "0"),end=" ") change end=" " into end="" this way it prints as you wish.

Answer (score -1):

```
import random
import time

for x in range(10):
      print(random.randint(0,1),end=' ')
      time.sleep(0.1)
print()
```