# python with for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, space

Hey I've got a problem with the for loop, 
so let say I want to achieve printing "#" signs 5 times with for loop with out space and in one line.

```
for i in range(5):
    print "#",
```

can how I get ride of the space in between  so it looks like ##### instead of # # # # #???

Comment: oh hey guys, the thing is that I try to not use the multiplcation(*) operator, or any repeat concatenation , and I have to use the for loop to print it out.

Comment: thanks everyone for help I've just found out how to do it!! thanks a lot. appreciate all the suggestion!!

Comment: ***Why*** are you trying to avoid these things? And ***why*** must you use a `for`-loop? If you explain your constraints in the question, you're more likely to get an answer that is suitable. Anyway, the answers for [How do I keep Python print from adding spaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255147/how-do-i-keep-python-print-from-adding-spaces) are still valid.

Comment: Are you saying you want an alternative to doing the easiest thing? Like homework?

Comment: oh its for a lab exercise, it has restrictions, and since we are learning to use for loops, the question asks us to not use multiplication operator or any repeat concatenation, but to use for loop only to achieve the result. Sorry for not clarifying this in the question.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you plan on doing things in this loop other than just printing '#', if that is the case you have a few options options:

```
import sys
for i in range(5):
    sys.stdout.write('#')
```

Or if you are determined to use print:

```
for i in range(5):
    print "\b#",
```

or:

```
from __future__ import print_function
for i in range(5):
    print('#', end='')
```

If you actually just want to print '#' `n` times then you can do:

```
n = 5
print '#'*n
```

or:

```
n = 5
print ''.join('#' for _ in range(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `print` *function* instead. (Note that in Python 2 `print` is normally a statement, but by importing `print_function`, it turns into a function).

```
from __future__ import print_function

for i in range(5):
    print('#', end='')
```

The function supports an `end` keyword argument, which you can specify.

Comment: To be clear, the distinction is that `print` is normally a keyword (Python 2.7 only I think), so this is a way of using a print *function*.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a join...  something like this should work:

```
print(''.join('x' for x in range(5)))
```

Comment: Alternatively, `print '#' * 5`.

Comment: True... probably even cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without a loop!

```
print '#' * 5
```

If you're making something more complicated, you can use `str.join` with a comprehension:

```
print ''.join(str(i**2) for i in range(4)) # prints 0149
print ','.join(str(i+1) for i in range(5)) # prints 1,2,3,4,5
```

Comment: I thought the OP didn't want a comma.  But, your join is absolutely correct if he does.

Comment: It was an example. But, I guess it is clearer without the comma. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah; but, your solution with the colums is really good for someone that needs it to be more complicated.  I liked it.  :)

Comment: Boy...  people really jumped all over this questions.  Lots of loops :)

Comment: OK, compromise. Commas *and* no commas!

Comment: @DavidS When I read the question I assumed that the OP wanted to do things other than just printing in his loop and those other things were removed from his example as they were immaterial to the question

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers posted, you could also:

```
mystring = ''
for i in range(5):
    mystring += '#' # Note that you could also use mystring.join() method
                    # .join() is actually more efficient.
print mystring
```

or you could even just:

```
print '#'*5
```

Comment: I don't think `mystring.join('#')` does what you think it does.

Comment: `mystring.join('#')` is a no-op...and building strings this way is not efficient.

Comment: That's why I'd just do `print '#'*5`. I think that the example though was meant to ask "How do I print without adding a space" since the unltimate simplest answer would be `print '#####'`

Comment: @BenMordecai I agree, I don't think the OP was really looking for `print '#'*5`

Comment: Edited my misleading join