# Python - Space between two characters

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def hashes(n):
    for x in range(0, n):
    print"#",
```

The above code produces the following result if n = 5:

```
# # # # #
```

Could anyone suggest a solution for making the characters have no space in between?

i.e

```
#####
```

(Python 2.7)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255147/how-do-i-keep-python-print-from-adding-spaces

Comment: It has nothing to do with your question but it would be nice if you correct indentation :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def hashes(n):
    print "#" * n
```

Comment: Didn't know you could do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With [print](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print) function

```
from __future__ import print_function
def hashes(n):
    for x in range(0, n):
        print("#", end='')
```