# Create a certain triangle with stars

Tags: python, loops, python-2.7, infinite-loop

I'm using python IDE wing version 4.1

I'm trying to write a function with only 1 input which will be an integer and return the next shape of stars:

```
  *
 **
***
```

I tried using the following code but it gave another shape:

```
from math import *
from string import *
def tri_1(n):
    x=n*'*'
    i=0
    while i<5:
        x=i*'*'
        i=i+1
        print x

n=input()
tri_1(n)
```

Comment: To save anyone running that code - what is this *other shape*?

Answer (score 0):

You need to think more carefully about what the algorithm should do. For each integer in the range `1` to `n` inclusive you want to print `n-1` spaces followed by `n` asterisks, so what is the hard-coded `5` doing there? Why don't you have *any* spaces? Given that you know how many times you will loop, why use `while` rather than `for`?

The most efficient way to achieve this is using the built-in string method [`rjust`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust), which pads the supplied string with spaces:

```
def tri_1(n):
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        print(str.rjust("*"*i, n))
```

Answer (score -1):

As this seems to be a basic programming exercise, I don't think we should rely on in-built functions too much. The following function gets the idea across.

```
def print_triangle(n):
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        for j in range(n-i):
            print(' ', end='')
        for k in range(i):
            print('*', end='')
        print()
```

Invoking `print_triangle(3)` will print

```
  *
 **
***
```

This function is a little shorter, but does the same thing.

```
def print_triangle2(n):
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        print(' '*(n-i), end='')
        print('*'*i)
```

Hope that helps.

EDIT:
Thanks Jon, I got so used to the Python 3 print statement that I forgot that the `end=''` part would not work unless you are using Python 3. This should work in Python 2.7:

```
import sys
def print_triangle(n):
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        for j in range(n-i):
            sys.stdout.write(' ')
        for k in range(i):
            sys.stdout.write('*')
        sys.stdout.write('\n')

def print_triangle2(n):
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        sys.stdout.write(' '*(n-i))
        sys.stdout.write('*'*i)
        sys.stdout.write('\n')
```

Comment: Note that it's tagged `python-2.7` so your use of `end=` in the prints isn't going to work...

Comment: @timgeb you can suppress the newline in python 2.x with e.g. `print "foo",` (note comma).

Comment: @jonrsharpe when testing this I still got a blank after each print.

Comment: @timgeb yes, that's called "softspace", see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255147/how-do-i-keep-python-print-from-adding-spaces