# Print multiple lines in one statement without leading spaces

Tags: python, python-3.x

So for my first project it is a simple program that prints your name class you are in and what high school you went to. The one thing that is messing me up is for one of them I have to use one `print()` statement for all this and I need to format it so that each piece of information is on a different line.

What I want for the format:

```
first_name, last_name
course_id, course_name, email
school
```

But what I get is

```
first_name, last_name
 course_id, course_name, email
 school
```

How do I remove the space?

My code is as follows:

```
first_name = 'Daniel'
last_name = 'Rust'
course_id = 'Csci 160'
course_name = 'Computer Science 160'
email = 'blah@gmail.com'
school= 'Red River Highschool'

#variables printed for B
print(first_name, last_name, '\n', course_id, course_name, email, '\n', school, '\n')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) inserts a space between each argument.  You can disable this by adding `, sep=''` after the last `'\n'`, but then there won't be any spaces between `first_name` and `last_name` or between `course_id` and `course_name`, etc.  You could then go on to insert `, ' '` manually where you need it in the `print` statement, but by that point it might be simpler to just give `print` a single argument formed by concatenating the strings together with explicit spaces:

```
print(first_name + ' ' + last_name + '\n' + course_id + ' ' + course_name
      + ' ' email + '\n' + school + '\n')
```

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/255172/2314532), you can use the `sep=''` argument to the `print()` function. That will let you set the separator between printed values (which is a space by default) to whatever you want, including an empty string. You'll have to remember to add spaces between the values that you *do* want separated. E.g.,

```
print(first_name, ' ', last_name, '\n', course_id, [...], sep='')
```

There's a better way to do this, involving the [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method on strings, but your professor is probably saving that one for the next lesson so I won't cover it in detail now. Follow the link to the Python docs, and read the section on Format String Syntax, if you want more details. I'll just show you an example of what your code would look like using `format()`:

```
print("{} {}\n{} {} {}\n{}".format(first_name, last_name, course_id, course_name, email, school))
```

Note no `\n` at the end, since `print()` automatically adds a newline unless you tell it otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reading through [str.format()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to print your information.

The spaces in your output come from the fact that you've called the print function, passing a list of strings, instead of passing the print function a single string.

```
print(first_name + ' ' + last_name + '\n' + course_id + ' ' + course_name + ' ' + email + '\n' + school)
```

yields

```
Daniel Rust
Csci 160 Computer Science 160 blah@gmail.com
Red River Highschool
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format would be a better link for him since he appears to be using Python 3.

Comment: I don't like this method because if any of the variables happen to be non-string you will run into problems.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't add space in your code

```
print(first_name, last_name, '\n',course_id, course_name, email, '\n', school, '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do so.
First can be str.format() as

```
print ('{} {}\n{} {} {}\n{}'.format(first_name, last_name, course_id, course_name, email, school))
```

Second can be

```
print (first_name, ' ', last_name, '\n',course_id, ' ', course_name, ' ', email, '\n',school, sep = '')
```

And the third can be

```
print (first_name + ' ' + last_name + '\n' + str(course_id) + ' ' + course_name + ' ' + email + '\n' + school)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple multiline print in python using f-string,

```
first_name = 'Daniel'
last_name = 'Rust'
course_id = 'Csci 160'
course_name = 'Computer Science 160'
email = 'blah@gmail.com'
school= 'Red River Highschool'

#variables printed for B
print(first_name, last_name, '\n', course_id, course_name, email, '\n', school, '\n')

print(f''' 
{first_name}, {last_name}
{course_id}, {course_name}, {email}
{school}''')
```

```
Daniel Rust
 Csci 160 Computer Science 160 blah@gmail.com
 Red River Highschool


Daniel, Rust
Csci 160, Computer Science 160, blah@gmail.com
Red River Highschool

[Program finished]
```

Answer (score -1):

**How to print several lines by using one print statement and how to add new line?**

```
pi = 3.14159 # approximate
diameter = 3
radius = diameter/2
area = pi * radius * radius
circumference = 2 * pi * radius
print("{}\n{}\n{}\n".format(area,radius,circumference))
```

output::
7.068577499999999
1.5
9.424769999999999

the above you will get corrcet answer for this code.