# Carriage return adding a space in print()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to understand why the carriage return is adding a space before the line in the print statement like the following:

```
print(1, '\n', 2, '\n', 3)
```

returning

```
1
 2
 3
```

Comment: broadly, it's `print()` adding them in .. you can use a structure like `"".join((vars..))`, simply append them together with `+`, or format them into a string to avoid this! (note the first two require you to call `str()`, while f-strings or `.format()` automatically do this for you

Comment: This has the required answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25676970/print-multiple-lines-in-one-statement-without-leading-spaces