# How To Print Iterated String together(without new lines) in Python?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, iteration

I Want the output to be 
xyz
but its coming like 

x
y
z
as I am iterating over my string in for loop but Still any Way to print string together after iterating?
My Simple Py Code =>

```
string='xyz'
for lel in string:
                        print lel
```

Comment: What was wrong with `print string`?

Answer (score 2):

You mean this?

```
string = "xyz"
for letter in string:
    print letter,
```

Update: According to your comment, you can do some other things:

a) Use sys.stdout

```
for letter in string:
    sys.stdout.write(letter)
```

b) Use the print function:

```
from __future__ import print_function
for letter in string:
    print(letter, end='')
```

More about in this SO answer: [How do I keep Python print from adding newlines or spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255147/how-do-i-keep-python-print-from-adding-spaces)

Comment: yea!! :P SomeThing like this but there are spaces Can I Remove them even?

Comment: @user3881949 on Python 3.x (or 2.x using `from __future__ import print_function`) you can use `print(letter, end="")`.

Answer (score 0):

Well I Was really being Dumb!! I Just Fixed it up :P Thnx For The Help everyone :)

```
string='xyz'
x=''
for lel in string:
                  x+=lel
print x
```

Comment: ... did you try: `print(string)`? Why do you think you have to rebuild the string? Also, if you have a list of strings like `['Hello', 'World']` you can use `join` to join the strings together: `', '.join(['Hello', 'World!']) -> 'Hello, World!'`.

Comment: :P I Know i just asked this Coz i Want to add something to every Char in the string in the loop which i Didn't mention here , its Working now Thnx

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a
'xyz'
>>> for i in a: sys.stdout.write(i)
xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
import sys
text = "xyz"
for l in text:
    sys.stdout.write(l)
```