# Printing integers on the same line reading from a text file

Tags: python-3.x, printing

Beginner needs some help

My code is below. I'm trying to get the integers to print out on the same line. I'm reading the them from a text file named "numbers.txt". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
def main():
    num_file = open('numbers.txt', 'r')
    for num in (num_file):
        print(num, end='')
    num_file.close()
    print('End of file')

main()
```

Here is my current output:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I keep Python print from adding newlines or spaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255147/how-do-i-keep-python-print-from-adding-newlines-or-spaces)

Comment: You should put language as a tag (helps getting attention from the right people)

Comment: @Drazisil this would not be a duplicate since here `end` is used in the `print` function which implies that this is Python 3 where `print` is a function and not a statement. The question you referenced is Python 2 where adding a comma at the end of the lists is used to prevent a newline being printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading a file line by line as you have done here with `for num in (num_file)`, the end of line characters do not get stripped off and are included with each line and stored in your variable `num`. This is why the numbers continue to print on separate lines even though you set `end=''`.

You can use `rstrip` to remove the new line character in addition to setting `end=''`. Also, the parentheses around `num_file` in your for loop are not necessary.

```
def main():
    num_file = open('numbers.txt', 'r')

    for num in num_file:
        print(num.rstrip('\n'), end='')

    num_file.close()
    print('End of file')

main()
```

To sum the numbers found:

```
def main():
    num_file = open('numbers.txt', 'r')
    total = 0

    for num in num_file:
        print(num.rstrip('\n'), end='')
        try:
            total = total + int(num)
        except ValueError as e:
            # Catch errors if file contains a line with non number
            pass

    num_file.close()
    print('\nSum: {0}'.format(total))
    print('End of file')

main()
```

Comment: Noah, thanks for the response. I tried this, but I'm still getting the same output. I'm thinking I need to read the file and build a range out of it before I print it.

Comment: @spbiknut For some reason I had removed `end=''`. You do need to keep that because the default value of `end` if not specified is `\n`. Put that back in your print function and try again. Sorry.

Comment: Noah, That did it! I understand it now...Thanks for your help!

Comment: Noah, one other question...is there a way to sum those numbers and print the total?