# Python 2.7.10: readline causes a leading space on the following line

Tags: python, io, formatting, stdout, stdin

I'm writing a simple command line prompt script and noticed that lines printed immediately after doing a readline start with a leading space. Is there any way to avoid this behavior?

Sample function to demonstrate:

```
import sys
def foo():
    print 'Enter some text.\n> ',
    bar = sys.stdin.readline()[:-1]
    print 'You entered "{0}"'.format(bar)
```

When I run this code I get:

```
>>> foo()
Enter some text.
> Hi
 You entered "Hi"
^ the leading space I want to get rid of
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Python 2's "soft-space" behavior. After a `print thing,` statement, the next `print` will print a leading space to separate the output from the previous print output. This can look weird when a different text source, such as user input, causes the output of the two `print`s to appear on different lines.

There are various ways to get around soft-spacing, but here, the most appropriate would be to use `raw_input` instead of `sys.stdin.readline`. It auto-strips the newline for you and allows you to specify a prompt:

```
print 'Enter some text.'
foo = raw_input('> ')
print 'You entered "{0}"'.format(foo)
```

Comment: Great, that fixed it. Wish I knew about raw_input before. I also found this related StackOverflow question when I Googled "python soft space" in case anyone else wants more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255147/how-do-i-keep-python-print-from-adding-newlines-or-spaces