# Printing numbers from a loop on a line python

Tags: python-2.7, loops, integer

Using

```
for i in range(5):
   print i+1,
```

it prints `1 2 3 4 5`
Is there anyway for it to print without any spaces e.g. `12345`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I keep Python print from adding newlines or spaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255147/how-do-i-keep-python-print-from-adding-newlines-or-spaces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to create a single string that gets printed once.  You can do

```
print ''.join(map(str, range(1,6)))
```

or

```
print ''.join(str(i+1) for i in range(5))
```

Or use the Python 3 compatible `print` function which takes an `end` argument.

```
from __future__ import print_function
for i in range(5):
    print(i+1, end='')
```

The `print` function also takes a `sep` argument so you can print your entire range in one go.

```
from __future__ import print_function
print(*range(1,6), sep='')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s=''
>>> for i in range(5):
...    s=s+str(i+1)
...
>>> s
'12345'
```