# Python | Nested for loop

Tags: python-2.7

Program to print following:

```
   *
  **
 ***
****
```

My program:

```
for i in range(1,5):
    for j in range(1,5-i):
        print '',
    for k in range(1,i+1):
        print "*",
    print
```

It prints:-

```
   *
  * *
 * * *
* * * *
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I keep Python print from adding newlines or spaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255147/how-do-i-keep-python-print-from-adding-newlines-or-spaces)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python will add new space between two `print " ",`
Simplify version:

```
for i in range(1,5):
    print " " * (5 - i) + "*" * i
```