# How do I remove the spaces when Python prints in for loop?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python. Trying to make a simple function that converts a string input to braille via dict values (with '1' indicating a bump and 0 no bump).

I'm sure there are faster/better ways to do this but what I have is almost working (another way of saying it doesn't work at all).

```
alphabet = {
'a': '100000','b': '110000','c': '100100','d': '100110'
#etc
}
def answer(plaintext):

    for i in str(plaintext):
        for key, value in alphabet.iteritems():
            if i in key:
                print value,            

answer('Kiwi')
```

This prints:

```
000001101000 010100 010111 010100
```

My question is how do I remove the spaces? I need it to print as:

```
000001101000010100010111010100
```

It's printing as a tuple so I can't use .strip().

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255147/how-do-i-keep-python-print-from-adding-newlines-or-spaces

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I keep Python print from adding newlines or spaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255147/how-do-i-keep-python-print-from-adding-newlines-or-spaces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what I'd consider a pythonic way:

```
def answer(plaintext):
    alphabet = { ... }
    return "".join([alphabet[c] for c in plaintext])
```

(this assumes that all letters in `plaintext` are in `alphabet`)

Comment: Thanks so much! This works perfectly. I understand the looping through each c in plaintext, and that the dict values are being joined without spaces, but can you briefly explain how the rest works - specifically the alphabet[c] ?

Comment: `alphabet` is a dict, so `alphabet[c]` is the encoding for that letter in the plaintext

Comment: I understand. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
brail = []
for i in str(...):
  if alphabet.get(i):
    brail.append(alphabet[i])
print ''.join(brail)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first line of the function, create a container  `l=[]` .Change the last statement inside the loops to `l.append(value)`.Outside the loops,but still inside the function, do `return ''.join(l)`. Should work now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join()` within a `generator` like this way:

```
alphabet = {'a': '100000','b': '110000','c': '100100','d': '100110'}

def answer(a = ''):
    for i in a:
        for key, value in alphabet.iteritems():
            if i in key:
                yield value

print ''.join(answer('abdaac'))
```

Output:

```
>>> 100000110000100110100000100000100100
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to manipulate printing in Python is to use the end parameter. By default it is a newline character.

```
print("foo")
print("bar")
```

will print like this:

```
foo
bar
```

In order to make these two statements print on the same line, we can do this:

```
print("foo",end='')
print("bar",end='')
```

This will print like this:

```
foobar
```

Hopefully this is a helpful way to solve problems such as this.