# Plese help me! I dont want to print spaces

Tags: python

Consider this question.

Write a function translate() that will translate a text into "rövarspråket" (Swedish for "robber's language"). That is, double every consonant and place an occurrence of "o" in between. For example, translate("this is fun") should return the string "tothohisos isos fofunon".

And my solution is given below:

---

```
a=[]
a=raw_input("Enter text which you whant to translate in 'roverspraket':\n").lower()
def translate(a):
    for char in a:
        if char is "a" or char is 'e' or char is 'i' or char is 'o' or char is 'u' or char is ' ':
            print char,
        else:
            print char+'o'+char,
print(translate(a))
```

---

Its output is given below:

```
Enter text which you whant to translate in 'roverspraket':
vinay<--- This is input
vov i non a yoy None
```

---

My question is i dont want space between these.... how can i do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I keep Python print from adding newlines or spaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255147/how-do-i-keep-python-print-from-adding-newlines-or-spaces)

Comment: you can use `end=''` in your print statement, like this `print(char, end = '' )` and `print(char+'o'+char, end = '')` which will give you `vovinonayoy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your problem I would have `translate` take an input string and return a modified string. That modified string can then be printed without problems. Here is my solution:

```
def translate(inp):
    out = ''
    for char in inp:
        if char not in ['a','e','i','o','u',' ']:
          out += char+'o'
        out += char

    return out

inp=input("Enter text which you whant to translate in 'roverspraket':\n").lower()

print(translate(inp))
```

Note:

- I have changed `raw_input` to `input`. The latter is the Python 3.x standard, since I saw you were using `print(...)`. If you want to use Python 2.x instead, you'll have to retain the `raw_input`.
- I have replaced your many `or`s with a more pythonic equivalent, by checking if `char` is in a list of characters. The behavior is fully equivalent. Only my version looks clear, and might even be faster?
- I have avoided a minor piece of code repetition by avoiding the `elif`. Although it really doesn't matter in this small bit of code, I wanted to point this out because it can be a bigger deal when you start writing more serious programs. See also [this TED talk of Linus Torvalds](https://www.ted.com/talks/linus_torvalds_the_mind_behind_linux) (which is mostly not about programming though...).

Comment: @VinaySharma. You're welcome. (If the question is sufficiently answered please mark the answer(s) that satisfy your need as answered.)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's more useful to return the extended string:

```
def rovarspraket(text):
    """ Translate text into robber-language """
    result = ""
    vowels = "aeiou"
    for char in text:
        result += char
        if char not in vowels:
            result += "o" + char
    return result
```

Comment: or simply (needs `import functools`): `return functools.reduce(lambda c1, c2: c1+c2 if c2 in "aeiou" else c1+c2+"o"+c2, text, "")`