# How to get rid of space between period

Tags: python

```
import datetime
from datetime import date
today = date.today()
user_name = input('What is your name? ')
user_age = int(input('How old are you? '))

print('Hello ' + user_name + '! You were born in', today.year - user_age, '.')
```

What is your name? Tyler
How old are you? 31
Hello Tyler! You were born in 1991 .

Process finished with exit code 0

how do i get rid of the space between the period at the end?

I tried using + but it wont work because its an integer

Comment: Don't give `print()` separate arguments with `,`, but construct a single string with `+` (like you did in the first half), or better yet use an f-string (like `f'Hello {user_name}!'` etc.).

Comment: `print(f"Hello {user_name}! You were born in {today.year - user_age}.")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove specific characters from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939361/remove-specific-characters-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: Thank you so much. Im currently in school and this is only my 2nd week learning how to code so I've got tons to learn. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Use an f string, just like this!

```
import datetime
from datetime import date
today = date.today()
user_name = input('What is your name? ')
user_age = int(input('How old are you? '))
print(f"Hello {user_name}! You were born in {today.year - user_age}.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the year into a string by wrapping it in the `str()` function and then use + to concatenate.

Answer (score 0):

`print()` adds spaces and new lines by default. You can utilize the `sep` argument to prevent spaces being injected:

```
print('Hello ' + user_name + '! You were born in ', today.year - user_age, '.', sep='')
```

See here:

[How do I keep Python print from adding newlines or spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255147/how-do-i-keep-python-print-from-adding-newlines-or-spaces)

Answer (score 0):

Use an f-string to print for greater control. By default print uses a space as a separator between seperate items.

```
print(f"Hello {user_name}! You were born in {today.year - user_age}.")
```